# Russian Roulette

Tags: code-golf, random

Write a program which plays Russian Roulette!

If the program is started,

- there should be a 5 in 6 chance of it ending normally after printing "I survived!"
- there should be a 1 in 6 chance of the program crashing. (segmentation fault, etc.)

No input, and no other outputs are allowed.

The randomness must be fair: it must have a uniform probability distribution. This means an uninitialized variable (or a RNG without seed) MOD 6 will not be sufficient.

If the solution works with only one dedicated operating system / platform, you will receive a 6 byte penalty to the score.

<sub>Shortest code wins, not sooner than 10 days after first valid answer.</sub>

Comment: Can we rely on the underlying runtime to be fair, even if not explicitly guaranteed in documentation? E.g. Python's `randrange(5)` might be implemented as `randrange(MAX_INT)%6`.

Comment: To inspire creativity, you might consider granting a bonus to those solutions which _don't_ rely on division by zero.

Comment: Perhaps said bonus should involve dividing the score by 2.

Comment: @JoeZeng : that would have been too much. Usually you can make it a different error, like null pointer reference, etc. for the cost of just a few characters.

Comment: I see. I'm not too experienced in creating scoring conditions for code golf puzzles, so I'm still learning stuff like that.

Comment: By "crash" will division by zero error be sufficient (i.e., not fatal in this case, but program does not continue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>13</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
6LΩiFë“IÐ–d!
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Emigna*.

05AB1E actually shouldn't be able to error at all, but since the new version of 05AB1E still has some issues compared to the legacy version, I can take that to my advantage to error out for this challenge.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fzOfcyky3w6sfNczxPDzhUcPkFMX//wE)

**Explanation:**

```python
6L          # Create the list [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  Ω         # Get a random choice from this list
   i        # If it is 1:
    F       #  Do a ranged loop, which currently results in a "(RuntimeError) Could not
            #  convert  to integer." error when no argument is given
   ë        # Else:
    “IÐ–d!  #  Push dictionary string "I survived!" (which is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `“IÐ–d!` is `"I survived!"`.

Comment: Seems like `5ÝΩz“IÐ–d!` should work but apparently `1 / 0 = 0`.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Yeah, 05AB1E almost never errors.. Apart from the pretty old builtin `.0` which used to throw a division by 0 error to STDERR in an old version of 05AB1E, I don't even know [how to error in the legacy 05AB1E at all](http://tinyurl.com/y63wzezm).. The new version still has quite a lot of errors however, which I took to my opportunity here. ;)

Comment: I miss the old `.0`, on more than one occasion it made someone go "Wat... Why is that a command?"

Answer (score 11):

### PHP 38 bytes

```
<?~$$s[rand(+$s=sssss,5)]?>I survived!
```

Placing a `+` before a non-numeric string will evaluate to `0`. Should `rand(0,5)` return `5`, `$s[rand(0,5)]` will be the empty string (since `$s` is only five characters long), and subsequently `$$s[rand(0,5)]` will be an uninitialized variable. Attempting to take the inversion will halt on Unsupported Operand Type. Any other value, `0-4` will return `s`, and because `$s` is defined, you will survive.

Note: as of php version 4.2.0, the random number generator is [seeded automatically](http://php.net/ChangeLog-4.php#4.2.0).

Answer (score 7):

### Dyalog APL - <strike>25</strike> <strike>22</strike> <strike>21</strike> 20 Charachters

```
'I Survived!'⊣1÷6⊤?6
```

Prints `DOMAIN ERROR` as the error, due to division by zero.

Shortest non-division by zero solution I could come up with is 23 characters.

```
('I Survived!'1)[~6⍷?6]
```

It throws an `INDEX ERROR`

[Try it here](http://www.tryapl.org/)

[APL Font here](http://wiki.nars2000.org/index.php/APL_Font)

Comment: I would like to accept it, but it does not seem to work. A few times it prints "`I survived`", but after printing `DOMAIN ERROR` once, it keeps printing only that. Even if I reload the site completely, it will never ever survive again.

Comment: @vsz How strange... It works in my Dyalog APL WS, and I remember testing it with TryAPL when I was done. It still works on my interpreter, but not on the website.  If this helps: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9086539/apl.png

Comment: I tried it with other interpreters, like http://ngn.github.com/apl/web/index.html but it doesn't work. Please provide a link to an interpreter where it works, possibly with an explanation whether the RNG must be seeded or is seeded automatically. Otherwise I'll have to accept the golfscript solution.

Comment: @vsz I have updated my post to reflect that I am using Dyalog APL.  I was under the assumption that tryapl was using Dyalog (and I am confident that it was when I submitted this post).  But now it seems to be missing the ? operator.  Either way, I am no longer confident in the RNG being seeded automatically.

Comment: `1÷0` is a `DOMAIN ERROR` in Dyalog but in ngn/apl it's `∞`.  The result from `?6` is 1..6 when `⎕IO←1` (default in Dyalog) and 0..5 when `⎕IO←0` (only option in ngn/apl).  In Dyalog, the PRNG can be seeded by setting `⎕RL`.  Initially it has some pre-determined default value.  If you set `⎕RL←0`, the PRNG is re-seeded fairly unpredictably by the OS.  TryAPL _is_ using Dyalog and [does support the `?` function](http://tryapl.org/?a=%27I%20Survived%21%27%u22A31%F76%u22A4%3F6&run).

Comment: @ngn it seems to be working again on TryAPL.  It was originally, then it wasn't, now it is again.  I am wondering if they changed something back in January of last year.  Are you affiliated?

Comment: It's quite possible that something was changed back then, we are occasionally updating the software behind TryAPL or experimenting with features of the website.  Am I affiliated?  If I tell you, I'll have to kill you... well, with a probability of 1÷6 :)

Comment: By the way, here's an 18-character solution: ['I survived!'⊣÷⍟?6](http://tryapl.org/?a=%27I%20survived%21%27%u22A3%F7%u235F%3F6&run)

Answer (score 7):

### R 30

```
"I survived!"[6*runif(1)<5||Z]
```

One time out of six, it will throw an error: `Error: object 'Z' not found`

Answer (score 6):

### Python, 96

```
from ctypes import*
from random import*
randrange(5)or pointer(c_int())[9**9]
print'I survived!'
```

If `randrange(5)` returns 0, then python will crash due to a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 6):

### Ruby, 24-28

```
p rand(6)<5?"I survived!":1/0
```

Approx each 6 time, there is a `ZeroDivisionError`

There is even a shorter version with 24 characters (Thanks to ugoren and histocrat):

```
6/rand(6);p"I survived!"
```

If you don't accept the `"` in the output, then I need 3 more characters. The first option (`puts`) adds a newline, the second (`$><<`) makes no newline:

```
6/rand(6);puts"I survived!"
6/rand(6);$><<"I survived!"
```

There is a [question about random number in ruby at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198460/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-ruby).
The seed with `srand` is automatically called with the seed being from the current time if it wasn't already called. (see [Julians comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198460/how-to-get-a-random-number-in-ruby#comment2164872_198486))

---

Primo had the idea for an extra bonus [to those solutions which don't rely on division by zero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9062/russian-roulette/9083#comment17890_9062).

My first solution can be shortened (28 characters) with a ``` undefined local variable or method ``a' for main:Object (NameError) ```

```
p rand(6)<5?"I survived!":a
```

Comment: Can be even shorter with `6/rand(6)`.

Comment: Does Ruby seed its RNG automatically?

Comment: You can trim another three characters by removing the control flow: `1/rand(6);p "I survived!"`

Comment: @ugoren / histocrat Thanks for your hints, I adapted my solution.

Comment: Another byte for you: no white space is required between `p` and `"I survived!"`. By my count, that's only 24 bytes.

Comment: @primo Thanks - I adapted my solution.

Comment: The no-newline version can also be reduced by a byte, replacing `print` with `$><<`.

Answer (score 6):

### J, 18

```
'I survived!'[q:?6
```

Failing with `domain error` when trying to factorise 0.

Comment: Does J seed its RNG automatically?

Comment: @vsz Yes, with `?`. You can use `?.` for fixed seed.

Answer (score 5):

### vba, 27

```
?1/int(6*rnd),"I Survived!"
```

used in immediate window.
On failure, an error window stating:
[image: division by zero]
appears

Comment: Missing the `!` in the text.

Comment: @steenslag , fixed

Comment: @SeanCheshire I've offered [an alternative](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10673/3862) to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

## Befunge - 48 chars

```
 v >91+"!devi"v
/?>?<v"I surv"<
 / / :
   :,_@#
```

Befunge's only randomness is the `?` operator, which sends you heading in one of four posible directions (`1/4` chance). By blocking one or two directions, you have `1/3` or `1/2` chance, and by combining these, you get `1/6` chance to get out of the program "alive".

The program crashes by doing a divive-by-zero. I guess it's implementation-specific what will happen (on Wikipedia it says the program should ask for the desired answer), but [befungee.py](https://github.com/programble/befungee) sort of crashes, or exits angrily:

```
$ for i in {1..6} ; do ./befungee.py roulette.befunge ; done
Error (1,2): integer division or modulo by zero
Error (3,2): integer division or modulo by zero
Error (1,2): integer division or modulo by zero
I survived!
Error (0,1): integer division or modulo by zero
I survived!
```

Answer (score 4):

### C, <strike>67</strike> <strike>65</strike> 62 chars

`rand()%8` doesn't lose fairness. Division crashes for `t=0`, gives true for 1 and 2 (retry), gives false for 3..7 (survived).
**EDIT:** The previous version used a temporary variable, which ended up completely unneeded. `2/(rand()%8)` implements both needed conditions.

```
main(){
        for(srand(time(0));2/(rand()%8););
        puts("I survived!");
}
```

Comment: It does. "no other outputs are allowed"

Comment: @vsz, somehow missed it. But anyway, with gcc/Linux it doesn't print anything. Also, strictly adhering to the standard, this requirement is impossible, because undefined behavior might print anything.

Comment: @vsz, fixed now - no extra output in any case. Also works with optimization, and 2 characters shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL <strike>56 44</strike> 40 + 6

```
 if 1/cast(ceiling(rand()*6)-1as int)<2print'I Survived!'
```

Credit Sean Cheshire for calling out cast as unnecessary

```
 if 1/ceiling(rand()*6-1)<2print'I Survived!'
```

Credit personal message from Sean Cheshire for suggestion to change ceiling to floor.

```
 if 1/floor(rand()*6)<1print'I Survived!'
```

Death Err Msg:
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: `-1` and `ceiling` are not needed. `cast` will truncate

Comment: I'm testing if ceiling can be removed without violating the requirement for uniform distribution, the docs say that rand() returns float values 0 through 1.

Comment: I wanted to know if ceiling could be removed from my first entry. I was unable to determine from T-SQL documentation if the rand() function would ever return a 1 or not. So I ran a loop about 50 million times testing the rand() function, never once did it return a 1. But, removing ceiling from my first entry would still be 47 bytes, so my second entry is still shorter. Keep ceiling and remove cast.

Comment: I doubt you have tested this script more than 20 times. This doesn't always return the expected result always. 1 in 6 this will fail and not return an output. This syntax will work: 0/floor(rand()*6)=0

Answer (score 3):

### **Python, 70 characters**

With inspiration from grc's answer.

```
from random import*
if randrange(5)<1:exec'()'*9**5
print'I survived!'
```

randrange(5) returns a value between 0 and 5.
If it returns a 0, Python crashes while attempting to exec(ute) a string of code that contains 9^5 sets of parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

Using the usual divide by zero method:

Perl 5.8 Version

```
1/(int rand 6)&&print "I survived!"
```

Perl 5.10 Version

```
1/(int rand 6)&&say "I survived!"
```

On failure, these will display:

```
Illegal division by zero at -e line 1.
```

Using the bless function which is used for creating objects in perl.

Perl 5.8 Version

```
print (int rand 6?"I survived!":bless me);
```

Perl 5.10 Version

```
say (int rand 6?"I survived!":bless me);
```

On failure, these will display:

```
Can't bless non-reference value at -e line 1.
```

Comment: a few suggestions: get rid of parentheses, the logical `&&`, and the extra space. use `~~` instead of `int` to force integral values. the result is this: `1/~~rand 6;print"I survived!"`

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript, 21 chars

```
,6rand/;'I survived!'
```

Like most of the answers, this one has a one in six chance of crashing with a ZeroDivisionError.  The shortest solution I could manage *without* using division by zero is 23 chars:

```
5,6rand=+;'I survived!'
```

which has a 1/6 chance of crashing with `` undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) ``.

(Ps. While developing this, I found what might be a bug in the GolfScript interpreter: code like `0,1>` appears to leave a `nil` value on the stack, which will later crash the program if you try to do anything with that value except pop it off and throw it away with `;`.  Unfortunately, the fact that I do need to use the value somehow to trigger a crash means that even exploiting this bug didn't help me get below 23 chars.)

Comment: That definitely seems like a bug. `5,5>` leaves `[]` on the stack, which is probably what it should do, but `4,5>` leaves `nil`. If you don't remove it, the interpreter will actually crash while trying to output it. An interesting side-effect is that `4,6rand>+;'I survived!'` becomes a valid solution. Someone should probably inform Flagitious.

Comment: I reported this, and it has been fixed (along with another bug I stumbled across) in the latest version of the GolfScript interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP - 30 bytes

```
<?rand(0,5)?:~[]?>I survived!
```

Requires PHP 5.4+ for the short array syntax, invalid operator idea shamelessly stolen from @primo.

As stated, [`rand()` is automatically seeded on first use](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/rand.c#63).

Comment: Division by zero does not halt, it only produces a warning, _as well as_ the text 'I survived!'. Also, `rand()%6` is not a uniform distribution, as `32768 = 2 (mod 6)`. However, `rand(0,5)||~$a` for 30 bytes is, and will additionally work with all PHP versions (the second expression in a ternary is only optional in 5.3.0+).

Comment: @primo Guess I was only looking for the stack trace when I was checking the divide by zero one, didn't notice it still printed. I know the ternary shorthand is 5.3+, but I really have no interest in supporting long out of date versions :)

Comment: That I agree with. There's no valid argument for continuing to use less than 5.3 at this point. 5.4, I'm still holding out for a double-digit revision number.

Comment: I count 29 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge, 38

```
v>25*"!devivrus I",,,,,,,,,,,@
?^
v
?^
<1
```

Pretty straight-forward. Crashing is done by pushing 1s onto the stack until it overflows. I made a few attempts at cutting out those 11 commas and replacing them with some more efficient loop to print everything, but couldn't get it under 11 characters.

Note that counting characters in Befunge is a little tricky... For instance there's only one character on the third line, but I'm counting an extra one there since execution could travel through that location.

Comment: I believe that's the record for the most consecutive commas I've ever seen in a program.

Comment: And then I look up how Befunge actually *works* and palm my face.

Answer (score 3):

## Python3.8.10 : 45

```python
int(set('12345 ').pop());print('I survived!')
```

I hope it follows the challenge specification.
I did some statistics with this method and it seems to have a uniform probability distribution
(the program crashes 10416 times over 60000 calls from the console)

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript, 42**

`(Math.random()*6|0)?alert('i survived!'):b`

The bitwise or floors the result of the multiplication thus a value between 0 and 5 results. 0 gets implictly casted to false, so in 5 of 6 cases the alert appears in the 6th case a certain `b` is referenced, crashing the process.

Answer (score 2):

### CMD Shell (Win XP or later), 40 +6

I'm only doing this one because DOS is not something that should even be thought of for code golf, and the whitespace is important

```
set/a1/(%RANDOM% %% 6)&&echo I Survived!
```

On failure, it will print

> Divide by zero error.

Answer (score 2):

## R, <strike>50 44 42</strike> 36

```
ifelse(!is.na(sample(c(NA,1:5),1)),'I Survived!',)
```

```
ifelse(floor(runif(1,0,5))>0,'I Survived!',)
```

```
ifelse(floor(runif(1,0,5)),'I Survived!',)
```

```
ifelse(sample(0:5,1),'I Survived!',)
```

Death Err Message:

> Error in ifelse(!is.na(1/sample(c(NA, 1:5), 1)), "I Survived!", ) : 
>     argument "no" is missing, with no default

Comment: I tried R, and couldn't get it to fail - `if(1/0)"I Survived!"` still printed **I Survived**

Comment: Unlike other languages, R doesn't consider 1/0 to be a math error and doesn't stop execution, it just returns inf for 1/0. I think @vsz wants a breaking error for this round. But supposing vsz counted NA as the death error, I could get my program down to 41 characters: ifelse(sample(c(NA,1:5),1),'I Survived',)

Answer (score 2):

### Emacs-Lisp, 42 characters

```
(if (= (random 6) 5) 
    z (message "I survived!")
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript, 40 chars

In Javascript the divide-by-zero trick doesn't even work: it just returns Infinity. Therefore, referencing a non-existing variable:

```
alert(6*Math.random()|0?"I survived!":f)
```

Not so short, though fun :)

Answer (score 2):

**PowerShell, 40 Chars**

```
IF(6/(Get-Random -Max 6)){'I Survived!'}
```

On Failure: "Attempted to divide by zero."

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6XC1kxfw0BPz7QmKDEvJT9Xk0vdUyG4tKgssyw1RVH9/38A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/d/TTcNMXyMoMS8lP1fBTFOzWt1TIbi0qCyzLDVFUb32fy0Xl6GenqFBjWq1mkqagjpQCAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 53 bytes

Here's a short 53 byte python index out of range program:

```
import time
[0][time.time()%6<1]
print("I survived!")
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please note that in the rules for this challenge, it states "MOD 6 will not be sufficient." Although I'm not familiar with Python, it looks to me like you are using Modulo here.

Comment: @ShaunBebbers The quote is "This means an uninitialized variable (or a RNG without seed) MOD 6 will not be sufficient," but this [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/is-the-current-time-or-date-with-modulo-random-enough) says that current time modulo is enough for a PRNG for code-golf

Comment: My misunderstanding then.

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 28 bytes

```
r?<?
"< <@,ka"I survived!
 =
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/v8jexp5LyUbBxkEnO1HJU6G4tKgssyw1RZFLwfb/fwA)

Errors with a segmentation fault.

### Explanation

Befunge-98 adds some extra features (`r`, `k`, and `=`) that can be used to further golf [Joe K's Befunge-93 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10670/95679).

The first line (`r?<?`) calculates the 1/6 chance. The `r` initially reflects the IP to the left, where it reaches the second `?` and goes in a random direction. If it goes right, the `r` reflects it and it tries again. If it goes up or down, it moves onto the second line, and if it goes left, it moves onto the first `?`. There are three ways the IP can leave, so there is a 1/3 chance it moves onto the first `?`.
If it gets there, it again goes in a random direction. If it goes horizontally, it gets reflected (with either `r` or `<`) and tries again. This means that there are only two ways that the IP can leave, and they are equally likely. Either it goes down onto the second line, or it goes up and hits the `=` on the third line.

There is a 1/6 chance that `=` is executed (1/3 from the second `?` times 1/2 from the first). If it is, it does a system-execute call on the stack (which is empty and interpreted as an empty string). FBBI's implementation of this runs a C `system()` call on the empty string, which segfaults.

This leaves a 5/6 chance that the IP reaches the second line. If it does, it gets sent left with `<`, and pushes the string `"!devivrus I"` onto the stack. `ak,` prints the top 11 characters of the stack, outputting `I survived!` Finally, `@` ends the program.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
6X’’Xṛ“`:ƭ÷»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98s4lHDTCCKeLhz9qOGOQlWx9Ye3n5o9///AA)

### Explanation

```
6X            Generate a random number between 1 and 6 inclusive (using python randrange)
  ’’          Decrement it twice
    X         Generate a random number from 1 to the above value. 0 if the value is 0. Error if the value is negative (1/6 chance)
     ṛ        Right Argument; ignore the above value and instead return
      “`:ƭ÷»  "I survived!"
```

Unfortunately, taking the reciprocal of 0, dividing or integer-dividing by 0, and modulo by 0 all give either inf or nan, and don't actually error.

Comment: It's nice to have exactly one documented error in the docs for challenges like these.

Comment: @Razetime yep :D it's the only result when ctrl-f'ing "error" in jelly docs. of course there are a bunch of other ways but most of those errors come from writing the code wrong, not the actual runtime. i suppose i could get a line of STDIN which would EOF but IDK if that's allowed and this is easier anyway

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy, 39

```
1/new Random().next(6);print"I survived!"
```

Picks a random number between 0 and 5 inclusive. If 0, throws a divide by zero exception.

Answer (score 1):

**Java, 149**

```
public class R{public static void main(String[]s){int[]a={1,1,1,1,1};System.out.println(a[new java.util.Random().nextInt(7)]>0?"I survived!":"");}}
```

Fails with an "Array out of bounds" error. Managed to shave a few characters by using anonymous Random object (no imports).

Comment: 138 bytes https://tio.run/##FYyxDoIwFEV/pTq1g00cjIlonFlhJB0etDEPy4PQ16ohfHuF6Z7knNweEpx6@8658xCCqJYpth47ERh4mzSiFQMgyZpnpFdjQC1I3Jj2Qe4jdryYov4FdoMeI@tpy9iTbJvd99u/joxeV0B2HKTS5L5cEsurMvfz81iKEOeEydnD8QaqWNec/w

Answer (score 1):

### Python (56), Haskell (77)

This crashes with an IndexError when the generated number is 1:

```
from random import*
print['I survived!'][1/randint(1,7)]
```

The Haskell solution has the same idea:

```
import System.Random
main=putStrLn.(["I survived!"]!!).div 1=<<randomRIO(1,6)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, <strike>59 55</strike> 53, <strike>65 59</strike> 56

```
import os
1/(ord(os.urandom(1))%6)
print"I survived!"
```

`ZeroDivisionError` when `ord(os.urandom(1))%6` evaluates to 0

```
import os
print(["I survived!"]*5)[ord(os.urandom(1))%6]
```

`IndexError` when `ord(os.urandom(1))%6` evaluates to 5

Comment: Save 5 characters by changing the import: `import random as r` then use `r.randint`

Comment: Or save 8 characters by changing import to `import os`, then use `ord(os.urandom(1))%6` as your random int.

Comment: Save 1 character by removing the space after `print`.

Answer (score 1):

### VBA - 39/46

I don't love [Sean Cheshire's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9089/3862) numeric output (though still a good answer, it technically fails the `No input, and no other outputs are allowed.` from the spec...), plus he uses `/0`, so here are my alternatives:

```
?Mid("I Survived!",IIf(Int(6*Rnd),1,0))
```

This resolves to a `Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure` when trying to reach character 0 (VBA is 1-based indexing).

```
n="I Survived!":If Int(6*Rnd) Then ?n Else ?-n
```

This resolves to a `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch` when applying a negative switch to a string.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC (TI-84+/SE), 36 bytes

```
startTmr→rand:1/(1<randInt(1,6:"I survived!
```

There is no input, as the challenge specifies.
Output is `I survived!` if successful, a `DIVIDE BY 0` error otherwise.

The `DIVIDE BY 0` error screen looks like the following:

```
ERR:DIVIDE BY 0
1:Quit
2:Goto
```

Selecting either option (and returning to home screen if `2` is selected) shows `Error` after the program call.

**Examples:**

```
prgmCDGFE
           Error
prgmCDGFE
I survived!
prgmCDGFE
I survived!
prgmCDGFE
           Error
```

**Explanation:**

```
startTmr→rand:1/(1<randInt(1,6:"I survived!   ;full program

startTmr→rand                                 ;store the current time into "rand"
                                              ; this is necessary because "rand" is 0 after
                                              ; factory reset, the default state for TI-BASIC
                                              ; submissions
                   randInt(1,6                ;get a random integer in [1,6]
                 1<                           ;is greater than 1?  1 if true, 0 if false
              1/(                             ;divide 1 by the result
                                              ; throws "DIVIDE BY 0" error if result was
                                              ; false
                               "I survived!   ;leave this string in "Ans"
                                              ;implicitly print "Ans"
```

---

**Notes:**

- TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Byte count does ***not*** equal character count.
- Lowercase letters are **two bytes** each.

  - Lowercase letters can be enabled using [this](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/hexcodes#toc7) assembly program.
- `startTmr` is a command only on the TI-84+ and TI-84+ SE calculators.  Said calculators have different operating systems.

Comment: -4 bytes: to produce the error: `identity(randInt(0,5` (a zero-size identity matrix will error)

Answer (score 1):

GNU Bash -- 37 bytes

`!` followed by nothing doesn't trigger history substitution. `$[...]` is alternative syntax for arithmetic. `(...)` is a subshell.

This solution is portable. `bash` itself does `fork` but doesn't `exec` any other programs.

```
(exit $[$RANDOM%6])&&echo I survived!
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v1.4.5, 16 bytes

```
6ö
ªí
`I s¨viv!
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.5&code=NvYKqu0KYEkgc6h2aXaCIQ)

-1 byte thanks to @Shaggy!

Throws `TypeError: U.í is not a function` when a random number in the range `[0,6)` is `0`.

Comment: [17 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=NvYKqu0pqWBJIHOodml2giE)

Comment: Actually, it might be an idea to use v1.4.5 for this, just in case ETH adds an `N.í()` method to v1.4.6.

Comment: Updated - Japt tries hard not to crash on weird programs. I was trying to figure out how to reference a variable that didn't exist (A-Z is defined), but didn't consider calling a method that didn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, `N.í()` is my "go to" for throwing an error (it used to be `N.y()`). There are a few other ways of getting an error but they're rarely useful.

Comment: Now, why didn't I think of using a 3rd line?! :\

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 48 bytes

```cs
Write(1/new Random().Next(6)<9?"I survived!":"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/vCizJFXDUD8vtVwhKDEvJT9XQ1PPL7WiRMNM08bSXslTobi0qCyzLDVFUclKSUnz/38A)

Throws `Attempted to divide by zero.` if a random number in the range `[0,6)` is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

## VB.Net, 38 bytes

```
If(CInt(Rnd() * 6), "I survived!", Dir())
```

Throws : System.ArgumentException 'Dir' function must first be called with a 'PathName' argument.

Spaces removed :

```
If(CInt(Rnd()*6),"I survived!",Dir())
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :) Couple of things: you should include your solution's byte count in the header, I'm pretty sure you can remove all the spaces, and, could you use a single character, undefined function name instead of `Dir`? Also, does VB.Net have bitwise operators?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and tips - first attempt at code golf!  VB.Net will not compile an undefined function name, so I picked an inbuilt with the smallest number of chars.

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore C64/128, C64Mini and compatibles, <strike>101</strike> <strike>95</strike> 92 tokenised BASIC bytes + 6 penalty bytes for only working in Commodore BASIC

As Commodore keyword abbreviations, you may enter it as follows:

```
 0a$="i survived":fOi=0to5:a$(i)=a$:nE:a$(rN(.)*6)="":x=6*rN(.)
 1?len(a$(x))/len(a$(x))"{left}{left}"a$
```

I found a six-tokenised byte saving by not using the `INT` keyword when assigning a value with `RND` and CBM BASIC will automatically convert the key value to it's integer by ignoring the decimal places.

Non-obfuscated for explanatory purposes:

```
 0 let a$="i survived"
 1 for i=0 to 5
 2 let a$(i)=a$
 3 next i
 4 let a$(int(rnd(0)*6)=""
 5 let x=int(rnd(0)*6)
 6 print len(a$(x))/len(a$(x));"{left}{left}";a$(x)
```

Firstly, we set up `a$` as a string and we later use it as an array; in Microsoft [Commodore] BASIC that appeared on the PET, VIC-20, C64 etc... you can set up the first 11 elements of a zero-indexed array without expressly declaring it first, though it saves space on the variable stack if you do and you have fewer than 11 elements.

So our string array of six elements are set to the string literal of `i survived`. One of those elements is randomly reset to an empty string.

The `x` variable is then used to select which of the six will be displayed (one of which is empty). Finally, we try to divide the length of that element with itself; usually this would produce an output of `1` except where the string length of the element is `0`, so `0/0` will produce an error (one in six chance) and halt the execution of the symbolic listing; otherwise, the `print` command moves the cursor position back two spaces to overwrite the output with the string literal of the array element `x`, or `i survived`.

This answer assumes that the `division by zero` error reported by BASIC (which halts the programs execution by the interpreter) is acceptable as `the program crashing` as cited above.

[image: Commodore 64 Russian Roulette]

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

```python
import os
print["I survived!"][os.urandom(1)<'+']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PzO3IL@oRCG/mKugKDOvJFrJU6G4tKgssyw1RVEpNjq/WK@0KDEvJT9Xw1DTRl1bPfb/fwA)

Utilises the idea from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10669/82577) of using `os.urandom`, but we save some bytes by avoiding the `ord` call.

`os.urandom(n)` generates `n` random bytes. By checking if they are smaller than `chr(math.ceil(256.0/6)) (== '+')`, we get an approximately `1/6` chance of `True (== 1)`.

Comment: Is the chance one in six though? It's not clear so maybe an explanation will help.

Comment: @ShaunBebbers explanation added. Since `256%6 != 0` the chance is not exactly one in six, but many answers here approximate those odds slightly.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `O`, 13 bytes

```
6ʁ℅ḭ`I ¦⟇d!`,
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=O&code=6%CA%81%E2%84%85%E1%B8%AD%60I%20%C2%A6%E2%9F%87d!%60%2C&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Fixed thanks to Razetime!

When run offline, 11 bytes (thanks to Aaron Miller)

```
6ʁ℅ḭ`I ¦⟇d!
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=6%CA%81%E2%84%85%E1%B8%AD%60I%20%C2%A6%E2%9F%87d!&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: The challenge states "no other outputs allowed"; when it errors, it prints `0` to STDOUT

Comment: You can disable implicit output with the `O` flag, also I got it to error: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=O&code=6%CA%81%E2%84%85%5B%60I%20%C2%A6%E2%9F%87d!%60%2C%7C%E1%B8%AD&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: @Makonede Fixed.

Comment: [This](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=6%CA%81%E2%84%85%E1%B8%AD%60I%20%C2%A6%E2%9F%87d!&inputs=&header=&footer=) is a valid 11 byte solution, because when run offline, it errors 1/6 of the time without printing anything.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 64 bytes

```
puts [expr srand([clock se])*0+int(rand()*6)%6?"I survived":1/0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCE6taKgSKG4KDEvRSM6OSc/OVuhODVWU8tAOzOvRAMsrKllpqlqZq/kqVBcWlSWWZaaomRlqG8Q@/8/AA)

Answer (score 0):

### C++, 105 bytes

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
int f(){srand(time(0));delete(int*)!(rand()%6);printf("I survived!");}
```

In C++, `delete` behavior is that on 0 ( or nullptr ), nothing occurs

Not as cool ( nor dangerous ) as [CommitStrip's russian roulette](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2014/05/16/russian-roulette/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Microscript II](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Microscript-II), 20 bytes

```
6R("I survived!"ph)f
```

Generates a random integer on `[0,5]`, printing the message and halting if the generated integer is nonzero. If the generated integer is 0, it instead crashes with an IllegalArgumentException because the `f` instruction is invoked on a nonstring value

Comment: Can you add an explanation for those not familiar with Microscript?

Comment: @streetster done

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 51 bytes

```forth
include random.fs
: f 1 6 random / ." I Survived!";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYwxD4IwFAZ3fsUHi5MYFwedSXTVER0qfS0vqa/ktZDon6@YOF3uhnNR87j17odSWIYwW4IasfHVulQd4bDH4V@wQ9vggtusCy9k6@ZUzt21QyKyqHFH5ggbKckmg4Uzm8AfQh45YdI4kYZ31T/JszzW9aDojTerlC8)

#### Explanation

Randomly gets a number between 0 and 5 (inclusive)
Divides 1 by the result
Crashes with divide by zero error if random number is 0

#### Code Explanation

```forth
include random.fs       \ include the library file necessary for random to work
: f                     \ start a new word definition
  1                     \ place 1 on the stack
  6 random              \ get a random number between 0 and 5 (inclusive)
  /                     \ divide 1 by the result of the random call
  ." I Survived!"       \ print "I Survived!"
;                       \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 0):

## JVM Bytecode `-noverify`, 372 bytes

Works by passing a wrong type to the print function if Random.nextInt(6) is 0.

Hexdump of the class:

```
$ xxd.exe Code.class
00000000: cafe babe 0003 002d 0020 0c00 1900 1f01  .......-. ......
00000010: 0016 285b 4c6a 6176 612f 6c61 6e67 2f53  ..([Ljava/lang/S
00000020: 7472 696e 673b 2956 0100 106a 6176 612f  tring;)V...java/
00000030: 7574 696c 2f52 616e 646f 6d01 0006 3c69  util/Random...<i
00000040: 6e69 743e 0c00 0400 0803 0000 0006 0700  nit>............
00000050: 1001 0003 2829 5607 0014 0100 0443 6f64  ....()V......Cod
00000060: 6501 0004 6d61 696e 0900 0900 0101 000a  e...main........
00000070: 536f 7572 6365 4669 6c65 0100 076e 6578  SourceFile...nex
00000080: 7449 6e74 0c00 1100 1a01 0013 6a61 7661  tInt........java
00000090: 2f69 6f2f 5072 696e 7453 7472 6561 6d01  /io/PrintStream.
000000a0: 0007 7072 696e 746c 6e0a 0013 001d 0700  ..println.......
000000b0: 0301 0010 6a61 7661 2f6c 616e 672f 5379  ....java/lang/Sy
000000c0: 7374 656d 0a00 1300 050a 0007 000f 0100  stem............
000000d0: 0428 4929 4907 000a 0100 036f 7574 0100  .(I)I......out..
000000e0: 1528 4c6a 6176 612f 6c61 6e67 2f53 7472  .(Ljava/lang/Str
000000f0: 696e 673b 2956 0100 0b49 2073 7572 7669  ing;)V...I survi
00000100: 7665 6421 0800 1b0c 000e 0017 0100 0001  ved!............
00000110: 0015 4c6a 6176 612f 696f 2f50 7269 6e74  ..Ljava/io/Print
00000120: 5374 7265 616d 3b00 2000 1800 1300 0000  Stream;. .......
00000130: 0000 0100 0900 0b00 0200 0100 0a00 0000  ................
00000140: 2900 0500 0100 0000 1db2 000c bb00 1359  )..............Y
00000150: b700 1512 06b6 0012 9a00 0812 06a7 0005  ................
00000160: 121c b600 16b1 0000 0000 0001 000d 0000  ................
00000170: 0002 001e                                ....
```

Jasmin code to generate:

```
.source ""
.class Code
.super java/util/Random
.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .limit stack 3
    getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    new java/util/Random
    dup 
    invokenonvirtual java/util/Random/<init>()V
    ldc 6
    invokevirtual java/util/Random/nextInt(I)I
    ifne Survive
    ldc 6
    goto Print
    Survive:
    ldc "I survived!"
    Print:
    invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    return
.end method
```

Must to be run with java -noverify to prevent Java from realizing that the class is messed up.

Also it's very wrong this time but CFR output for fun:

````
/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0.142.
 */
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Random;

class Code
extends Random {
    public static void main(String[] arrstring) {
        if (new Random().nextInt(6) != 0) {
            String string = "I survived!";
        }
        System.out.println((String)6);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Lol, submit the class file as a cfr 'bug', then I can fix it.

Comment: @lab27 Not exactly something one could fix, it uses a cast that isn't actually valid and some other silliness

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), <s>58</s> 53 bytes

-5 bytes by using &i in place of time(0) - thanks ceilingcat
`Floating point exception` when `rand()` is divisible by 6

```c
main(i){i/=(srand(&i)+rand()%6);puts("I survived!");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzOlPfVqO4KDEvRUMtU1MbzNBUNdO0LigtKdZQ8lQoLi0qyyxLTVFU0rSu/f8fAA)

Comment: ceilingcat that was in my original code but I wasn't sure if the pointer value changed across runs (I'm not that good at C)

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzOlPfVkMjM69EUy1T1UzTuqC0pFhDyVOhuLSoLLMsNUVRSdO69v9/AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 34 bytes

```perl6
(^6 .roll&&say "I survived!")||die
```

Throws an exception to crash.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/18jzkxBryg/J0dNrTixUkHJU6G4tKgssyw1RVFJs6YmJTP1/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 15 bytes

```
6rw/;'I ûÄ%$╦'!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9@sqFzfWt1T4fDuwy2qKo@mLlNX/P8fAA)

### Explanation

```
6r                push [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  w               random item from list
   /              divide implicit zero by the random element
    ;             discard TOS (needed for non-crashes)
     'I           push single character "I"
                  space character
        ûÄ%       push "Ä%"
           $      convert to ordinal (from base 256 to base 10)
            ╦     fetch single dictionary word "survived"
             '!   push single character "!"
```

With some better handling of dictionary fetches, this could probably be 2-3 bytes shorter, but that's not getting implemented within the immediate future.

Answer (score 0):

## Octave 33 bytes

```
{"I_Survived!"}(1/(rand(1)>0.16))
```

Approx each 6 time, there is a 
`warning: division by zero
error: index (inf): subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^31)-1 or logicals`

Comment: It prints way more than "I survived" and the rules say no other input than that is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 98 bytes

```java
interface m{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(Math.random()<.16?1/0:"I survived!");}}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Dci7DoIwFADQX6lMdKDK4qAmLi4OTiwmxuHalxdoa9pLE0L4datnPD1kaHo1lIKedDQgNXNLIiCULAdUzAH6uqOI3j6ewJduTqSdCBOJzz@pvgG9RQSvgqv5SbT7c7vdHaorS1PMmLXaVPy4rqV8pRnBptLcL2h9iFqk2b3CKAyO@gc)
Bonus answer that allocates `2^60` bytes of memory instead of dividing by 0:

```java
import sun.misc.Unsafe;import java.lang.reflect.*;interface M{static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{Field f=Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");f.setAccessible(1>0);((Unsafe)f.get(null)).allocateMemory(Math.random()<.16?1L<<60:0);System.out.print("I survived!");}}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##LY9PSwNBDMW/ytrTjNDQXnpwa0WogmBPRRDEQzqb2abOnzJJV0vpV3ddrbeQ915@eTvscLxrPvqe4z4XreSQILI4eEmCnur/9W7wQcDUQiEfyClc15yUikdH1eokisqu6jI3VUROZq2FU/v2jla3JX9K9fDlaK@c0@mRKTSVv70QwAUUgZZ0ScNYqPnTzUi3dHGMbO1BSO@dIxHeBDLTxcTWxlx063/TJh1CsBYwhOxQaUUxl6NZoW6hYGpyNHYO09nd9Hk@n01uhgProyhFyAeF/fCtmtHT0L903FFzNVDP577/dj5gK/34dcltyoVAjnGTA3gO9AM)

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 23 bytes

```
>6'RA0)?;"I survived!"@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/9/OTD3I0UDT3lrJU6G4tKgssyw1RVHJ4f9/AA)

Nothing too special here. Just an IP that picks a random number [0-6) and prints the required string if the random value isn't 0.

Required string contains two `v`s which also creates an IP each that get terminated after 100k execution steps (otherwise TIO would produce instant results and the `>` wouldn't be needed).

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB/Octave, 37 bytes

```matlab
a=1:5;a(randi(6));disp("I survived!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/0dbQytQ6UaMoMS8lU8NMU9M6JbO4QEPJU6G4tKgssyw1RVFJ8/9/AA)
It has 1 in 6 chances to crash with indexing error, when `randi` returns `6`.

Answer (score 0):

## PPL, 96 bytes

```js
importRandom
declarex=Random.random()*6
ifx>1{
printLine("I survived!")
}
ifx<=1{
printLine(f)
}
```

Very similar code to the Minceraft problem. Runs on PPL v1.0.10.

Soon, I will publish an official PPL website where you can create and run PPL code. I am still working on it.

### Explanation

The first line imports `Random`.

Then, we set `x` to `Random.random()` (random float between 0 and 1) multiplied by `6`.

Since neither `else` nor ternary exists in PPL, we must use two diverging if-statements. One prints the string `I survived!` to STDOUT (if `x` is greater than 1) while the other errors because `f` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

*Ties [hyper-neutrino's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225675/94066) for #1.*

```
“IÐ–d!“6LΩiF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMcz8MTHjVMTlEEMs18zq3MdPv/HwA)

```
“...“6LΩiF  # trimmed program
“...“       # push "I survived!"
        i   # if...
       Ω    # random element in...
      L     # [1, 2, 3, ...,
     6      # ..., literal...
      L     # ]...
        i   # is 1...
         F  # then do nothing...
“...“       # "I survived!"...
         F  # times
            # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), <sup><s>21</s></sup> 19 bytes

```
=?6/`p"I survived!"
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%3D%3F6%2F%60p%22I%20survived!%22&inputs=)

There's a 5/6 chance that this just prints `I survived`, and a 1/6 chance that this exits with an error:

```
Error: float division by zero at command index 1 [/`]
```

## Explanation

```
=?6           sets the top of the stack to a random value from 0-5 inclusive
   /`         divides the top of the stack by the top of the stack. 
                  This works fine except for when the top of the stack is 0
     b"..."   adds "I survived!" to the output buffer, implicit output (p" " would work here too)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 19 bytes

```
6?/<"I survived!"&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9/MXt9GyVOhuLSoLLMsNUVRSS3//38A)

This is similar to some of the other entries.  It generates a random number between `0` and `5`, then crashes with a division by zero error if `0` was the result.

```
6?                   - generate a random number in 0-5
  /                  - divide, fails with division by zero 1/6 of the time
   <                 - switch to a clean stack
    "I survived!"    - push the output string (codepoints)
                 &o  - print the stack a characters
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 32 bytes

```julia
0%rand(0:5);print("I survived!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPhfnpGZk6pQUlSa@t9AtSgxL0XDwMpU07qgKDOvREPJU6G4tKgssyw1RVFJ839qXsp/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## APOL, 28 bytes

Dead simple, just uses the "divide by 0" method.

`/(1 ∿(0 5));p("I survived!")`

Answer (score 0):

## [<>^v](https://github.com/Astroide/---v), 18 bytes

```
5#=V"I survived!";
```

[run online](https://v.astroide.repl.co/#cb383dce05ed9e0c1c63f1a51d5b19aa43640fd65b06a2948d118f76c41a3a7e)

#### Explanation

```
5#=V"I survived!";
5                  Push 5 to stack
 #                 Push random number in range [0, <top of stack>]
  =                Skip next instruction if the top two elements (5 and the random number)
                   of the stack are equal
   V               Try reading the value of register 'v'. This should crash because it was
                   never assigned a value, its setter 'v' being a keyword
    "              String start
     I survived!   Contents of the string
                "  String end
                 ; Print with newline
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 54 bytes

```python
import random;1/random.randrange(5);print'I survived!'
```

On 1/0 it will crash:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```