# Make your code error, but only sometimes!

Tags: code-golf, random

Your task is to create a program or function which **randomly** errors. Specifically, there must be a nonzero probability of erroring, but also a nonzero probability of running without error.

An error is anything that causes a program to terminate abnormally, such as dividing by zero or using an uninitialized variable. This also includes runtime errors, syntax errors and errors while compiling. Statements which manually throw an error, such as JavaScript's `throw` are allowed.

This program doesn't need to do anything if it doesn't error, other than exiting gracefully.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer per language wins.

**Note:** For this challenge, "randomly" follows [the current consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1325/79857) (so no using undefined behavior or uninitialized memory for randomness), and the program must be capable of producing both outputs if run or compiled multiple times (so a random number with the same seed is not valid)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152578/we-had-a-question-once-which-only-failed-on-sundays), though not about randomness

Comment: Does the error need to happen or not happen due to randomness, as opposed to something like varying state of memory or the current time or similar?

Comment: @xnor Randomness

Comment: @newbie Following the community consensus for ["random"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1325/79857)

Comment: I think it's a boring challenge. A lot of the answers are doing basically the same thing and there's little room for golfing. Note that downvotes don't necessarily indicate a challenge is ill-specified -- there's close votes for that.

Comment: Separately, I'm not so sure it's clear, since two of the upvoted answers rely on the state of memory when the program starts, despite the question in my earlier comment.

Comment: I don't really think the current definition of random, although settled, is really clear. For example, the python answer and the brainfuck answer below uses some degree of undefined behavior. The c answer, although fits that definition, won't really crash because of the lack of srand. So, I don't really like challenges based on such loose definitions (and when such definition matters a lot). I would change it to upvote if the question is updated, say, to, the program may or may not crash after a rerun/recompile.

Comment: @newbie Fixed. I suppose it was rather dumb on my part to assume answers would follow the established consensus without it being mentioned in the question.

Comment: It seems like so many users are posting `1/(random integer)` here...

Comment: @xnor: agreed, this turns out to be somewhat interesting in some assembly languages, but most high level languages make unpredictable behaviour intentionally difficult other than integer division, or a few other things where `0` is special.

Comment: What is "undefined behavior" specified as?

Comment: @S.S.Anne I'm just using "undefined behavior" to mean things that aren't random, but still vary or aren't defined in a specification (so, for example, you can't use uninitialized memory or the output of some operation with an output that varies by compiler as a source of randomness)

Comment: Some solutions fall into infloop sometimes, is it allowed given `doesn't need to do anything if it doesn't error, other than exiting gracefully.`?

Comment: @l4m2 That's a good question. I'd say it's fine, as I'm pretty sure my original intent was just "you're not allowed to error in the not-erroring case" (also I originally read that as "fall into floop" and wondered what the heck a floop was :p)

Comment: I want to attempt something like this for Arduino, but to quote an answer from the Arduino stack exchange: "There are no runtime exceptions. There is only undefined behaviour." (https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/189/what-happens-if-there-is-a-runtime-error)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Russian Roulette](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9062/russian-roulette)

Comment: @user I love how it auto-generated that comment even after I already VTCed it myself :p

Comment: @BrowncatPrograms so software. wow

Answer (score 33):

## [Baby Language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Baby_Language), 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVQ9b7MwEN75FS5LgwgVTZUMVZyhnSq9Q3fEQOAgSGAjY9Tm1@f1ByTGkKRD6wXw3T3P3XN3NEd@oOTllDNaI5aQTDzKuqGMq6@ScIdAy3HopIeEtdjd7vxg@RS5TgY5KoB8MlqwpF54rw4Sp6joPqmQcjYvJIj6ph1vOo5dV319HcoKBqZFuNx4aIdCDSUPgW@eYtN@NmkgHyuqSDnGZ2OZ61CEMdpc4DRkK6KeR3fKveVoi1bh2NtkMqudQAYW5BDkxrpSBrxjpL9W4omKgDXifrHPe/V40oCQWr7WUFN2xFGoi2qocO9NWjTpu62AXKLlSfE@j6RppEWKRePcV7tmDYpnSr6w@/p15AFVC9MYhWbK0BPvLGLlN9OBPhtZkub0ruXln2UxaHyLRrtGCjWeoRvZMV6tN9foBp/QpgxuUQZ3KYPne4yr9drmfLLVZHIz0gNbjEK9JQKS4cdHzwZYWgAFcFwSMZTWUAt32Qph9m6MyFSb6wMyjqAsk@Cik5MUo@moWtLNbWkDBLJ32p33xDx6ZwyfHQ4RZWjYlge5qFPQYSnt@TEyGxBm8r6S3s/A4p@BmWMGVS9gfEfAhz8RMLohYPCbNf9qN8zMhlbnlI7/9pd/tTB5juO6LvooCGWA3pL9Ef1LSNElBaB3msHpJMyn/w)

I *knew* this could be fun with a non-deterministic tarpit! I looked through the [category](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Category:Nondeterministic) on the *Esolang* wiki and found this language...

From the [page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Baby_Language):

> A Baby Language interpreter ignores the input program and does something random. (Likewise, a Baby Language compiler generates a random executable.) As such, whatever you wanted your program to do, there's an (admittedly small) chance that it will actually do it.
>
> The intended use case for the language is to run your program repeatedly until it does what you want. Just like trying to reason with a real baby, this may take quite a while.

So the blank program, and every program for that matter, executes a random program which will therefore randomly error!

#### Details on TIO link

I used *Esolang* user Enoua5's source code which generates and executes a random brainfuck program. It's linked on the Esolang page:

> An interpreter created in Python 3 by [User:Enoua5](https://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Enoua5): [View Source](https://pastebin.com/c5ZsULwH)

So the *TIO* link above takes you to Python 3 interpreter is implemented in the header and the actual (blank) code is in the (blank) code slot, which is ignored anyway!

The above interpreter is simply copied and pasted into the header; a multiline comment starting/ending in the header/footer nullifies the actual code.

Comment: I was shocked when I realized that such a boring language was created by Ais523...

Comment: ais523 is one of the more well-known esolang and code golf folks. I don't know if he's the *most* well-known, but I can't think of another one who's more well-known.

Comment: I'd say Dennis is more well known

Comment: I keep trying to run it, but all the random program does is factor RSA primes in polynomial time.

Comment: Best comment ever! And we'll never now what it's running...

Comment: @Lyxal And Martin Ender, and James, and Mego

Answer (score 21):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 2 bytes

```
‽‽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCMoMS8lPxdGaWpqWv///1@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 ‽  Random value (defaults to 0 or 1)
‽   Random element from implicit range
```

If the first random value is `1`, then the implicit range is simply `[0]`, so the random element is just `0`, which does nothing (it's implicitly printed, but printing `0` has no effect).

If the first random value is `0` however, then the implicit range is `[]`. This is an illegal input to `randrange` which therefore throws a ValueError.

Answer (score 17):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 8 bytes

```bash
m$RANDOM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P1clyNHPxd/3/38A)

If `$RANDOM` happens to have the value `4`, this will run the macro processor `m4` (which exits right away on TIO because stdin is empty). If `$RANDOM` has any other value, you'll get an error because there's no program available via $PATH with the indicated name.

---

If you want pure bash, with no external utilities, then the shortest I’ve found is my first version (which is 12 bytes long):

```bash
((1/RANDOM))
```

Comment: Hooray, an interesting one. :)

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 11 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to @newbie!*

```python
1/(id(0)%3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/31BfIzNFw0BT1Vjz/38A)

**Also 11 bytes**:

```python
id(0)%3or a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzNFw0BT1Ti/SCHx/38A)

**How**: The `id` of an object varies across different runs. Thus `id(0)%3` can be `0`, which causes `ZeroDivisionError` and `NameError` in the programs above respectively.

Comment: -3byte: `1/(id(0)%3)`

Comment: is it possible for an id to be 0?

Comment: @CommandMaster This is very iffy here since id is implementation dependent. In CPython, id is the address of an object in memory, so it's probably can't be zero. I've read somewhere that most Python implementations randomize the starting address of the stack/data to prevent some sort of attack, which is the behavior being used here. But can't find any documentation on this at the moment.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum: Python itself doesn't have to randomize addresses; OSes do ASLR of at least the stack, and often also static code/data if possible. (e.g. on GNU/Linux that requires a PIE (Position Independent Executable) which is why distros now configure gcc with that as the default.)  e.g. if you wrote a C program that did `printf("%p\n", main)` to print the address of main when you run it, you'd see a different address each run.  Unless you compile with `gcc -fno-pie -no-pie`.  related: [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427)

Comment: ASLR = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization.  It's a security feature so exploits like buffer overflows don't know a fixed address to overwrite a return value with.  Unless they can get the target of the attack to "leak" a pointer somehow first.  (Non-executable stacks defeat code injection via returning to the address of the stack, but other attacks like "returning" to the address of `system()` in libc with a pointer to `"/bin/sh"` in the right register would still work if an attacker knew that address.)

Comment: Techniques like that are the basis of so-called ROP attacks - return-oriented programming.  Finding little snippets of machine code ("gadgets") at fixed addresses can let you chain together a sequence of return values to eventually make something happen.  All of this is much harder to actually exploit if addresses are randomized, instead of identical on every server running the same version of some software.  Ok, that should be enough for anyone to google more if they're curious :P

Comment: @PeterCordes good read, thanks!

Comment: Can an id be 1? If so, then you could do `"a"[id(1)]` and shave one byte.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts I don't think so, id generally is a big number. If id can be 1, `1/~-id(1)` would also work.

Comment: Also 11: `0>>id(0)%-3`

Answer (score 13):

includes 3 different answers, smallest first

## x86-64 machine code "function", 4 bytes

("works" in all 3 modes: 16-bit, 32-bit, and 64-bit.  In other modes, FE 00 is a jmp to eax or ax.)

```
0000000000401000 <timejump>:
  401000:       0f 31           rdtsc           # EDX:EAX = timestamp counter
  401002:       ff e0           jmp    rax      # "return" with jmp to register
```

This function can be called with `jmp` instead of `call`; it doesn't need you to pass it a return address on the stack.   **It uses the low 32 bits of the time counter as a jump target, which might or might not be the correct return address (or somewhere else useful).**

The crash possibility is code-fetch from an unmapped or non-executable page, or jumping to instructions that fault (e.g. `00 00  add [rax],al`), or to an illegal instruction, like a `1F` or other byte somewhere in 64-bit mode, or a multi-byte illegal sequence in 16 or 32-bit mode, that will raise #UD.

RDTSC sets EDX:EAX = the number of reference cycles since power-on (i.e. the TSC = TimeStamp Counter, SO [canonical Q&A about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772567/how-to-get-the-cpu-cycle-count-in-x86-64-from-c/51907627#51907627).  Note that it doesn't count core clock cycles on modern x86).  The reference frequency is normally close to the CPU's sticker frequency (e.g. 4008MHz on a nominally 4GHz i7-6700k) so **the low 32 bits wraps around in just over 1 second, which is close enough to random for interactive use.**  Or every few seconds on chips with lower "base" frequencies.

Assuming a valid return address or other jump target exists in the low 32 bits of virtual address space, we have a `1` in `2^32-1` chance of reaching it.  Or higher if there are multiple useful targets to dispatch to.  (Assuming TSC is uniformly distributed, and fine-grained enough that every 32-bit low half is actually possible.  I think this is the case.)

In 32 and 16-bit mode, every possible address (in the same code segment) is reachable, but 64-bit mode unfortunately still splits the TSC between EDX and EAX so most of the 64-bit (or 48-bit) address space is unreachable.

On systems like MacOS where 64-bit processes normally have all their code outside the low 4GiB of address space, use 32-bit mode.  Linux non-PIE executables are mapped in the low 2GiB of virtual address space so any non-library code will be reachable.

---

## x86 32-bit machine code function, 5 bytes

```
0000000000401000 <inctime>:
 8049000:       0f 31                   rdtsc           # EDX:EAX = timestamp counter
 8049002:       40                      inc    eax      # EAX++
 8049003:       ce                      into            # trap if OF==1
 8049004:       c3                      ret
```

On most x86 CPUs, the TSC is fine-grained and really can be any value in the low half, including 2<sup>31</sup>-1.  So incrementing it can produce signed integer overflow, setting OF.

Also works in 16-bit mode (incrementing only AX with this machine code), but not 64-bit mode where [`into`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/intn:into:int3:int1) isn't a valid opcode.

## x86-64 machine code function, 6 bytes

(same machine code works in all 3 modes, using the default operand size for the mode; 16, 32, and 32.)

divides 64-bit user input by a random number: can overflow or divide by 0.

```
0000000000401000 <divrandom>:                          # input in EDX and EAX
  401000:       0f c7 f1                rdrand ecx
  401003:       f7 f1                   div    ecx       # return EDX:EAX / ECX
  401005:       c3                      ret
```

Yup, x86 has a *true* RNG built in (Intel since IvyBridge, and AMD since at least Zen).

x86 division of 64-bit EDX:EAX / 32-bit ECX => 32-bit quotient and remainder faults (with a #DE exception -> SIGFPE or other OS signal) if the quotient doesn't fit in 32-bit EAX.  With a small dividend, this can only happen on divisor = 0, 1 chance in 2^32.

With function input in EDX:EAX above 2^32-1, small divisors could leave a quotient larger than 2^32-1.  So the chance of faulting depends on the input value.  Specifically, division runs without faulting if ECX > EDX, where ECX is the random divisor and EDX is the high half of the 64-bit input.

---

[`rdrand`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdrand) always sets OF to 0 so we can't use 1-byte [`into`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/intn:into:int3:int1) conditionally trap on overflow.  (It only sets CF = success, 0 means HW RNG temporarily exhausted).

---

I can't think of any "unpredictable / undefined behaviour" situation that could actually give different results on different runs, other than meltdown-style timing that depends on microarchitectural conditions.

Some old ARM and MIPS CPUs have unpredictable behaviour that depends on timing if you for example use a multiply where the destination is one of the inputs, or on MIPS I read the result of a load in the next instruction (in the load delay slot).  So for example on MIPS `lw $ra, ($a0)` ; `jr $ra` (4 bytes each) might use the original return address in `$ra` (the link register) if the load hits in cache, otherwise it stalls and we'd return to wherever the load points.

Comment: That's cool but I think only the last one is valid. The rest rely on "undefined behavior", so to speak.

Comment: @S.S.Anne: I don't see anything "undefined" in the C UB sense of the word.  My source of run-dependent behaviour is a well-defined fast fine-grained counter.  I'm not getting "random" data from reading uninitialized memory or something that Intel's manual say is an "undefined" result (like `bsf reg,reg` with reg=0) but which is actually the same every time on real hardware.  That's what the question wording is excluding, I think.  I'm fairly confident that on at least some implementations, the TSC can have a low half of `0x7FFFFFFF`, or that it can be whatever return address the caller wanted.

Comment: @S.S.Anne, sampling a high-frequency counter at an arbitrary time is a perfectly valid source of randomness -- a number of hardware random number generators do exactly that.

Comment: So it turns out if you read the result register in the load delay slot it's actually well defined. It reads the previous value. The reason this is unpredictable is the CPU doesn't unwind on interrupt so unless you turned interrupts off the value is trashed. So yeah, outside of an interrupt handler it doesn't work.

Comment: @Joshua: Oh, so a cache-miss load on R2000 doesn't stall until after running the load-delay instruction?  Hmm, what about an I-cache miss after the load, before the delay slot?  (Maybe I was mis-remembering or mis-interpreting something I'd read about cache misses, if the source I got this from was correct at all).  You're saying it's well-defined and guaranteed to still let the next instruction read the old value, even with I-cache or D-cache misses, as long as there's no interrupt?  Do you have a link I can add to this and/or other answers if/when I fix this claim I've repeated?

Comment: @PeterCordes: Sorry wrong delay. Turns out I was talking about the delay after MUL instruction.

Answer (score 8):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

*idea and -2 bytes from @apsillers*

Uses `new Date` instead of `Math.random`, has a \$\frac{1}{9}\$ chance of not erroring:

```js
new Date%9&&a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py@1XMElsSRV1VJNLfH/fwA)

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

*-1 thanks to @newbie*

```js
Math.random()&&a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/3zexJEOvKDEvJT9XQ1NNLfH/fwA)

This has a \$\frac{1}{2^{1074}}\$ chance of not erroring, as `Math.random()` can occasionally be 0.

Comment: Remove the `!` to -1 byte.

Comment: stretching the definition of "non-zero probability"

Comment: It would be interesting to see V8's implementation of `Math.random` and a demonstration that it really is possible for the result to be `0.0`.

Comment: @TannerSwett If it was impossible for it to be `0.0`, it wouldn't be following the spec, which says the result should be in the range of `[0, 1)`

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms The spec says that the result should be greater than or equal to 0, but it never specifies that it _must_ return 0.  An implementation that never returns 0 is returning values that are greater than or equal to 0, and is compliant with the spec.  I think modern V8 uses xorshift128+, which should have more than enough state/period to sometimes return exactly 0, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: "occasionally" :p

Comment: @GrandOpener - Incorrect. It very much specifies that. It specifies that all values along that range (which includes 0) must have roughly equal probability of being output. So yes...it _must_ be capable of returning 0.

Comment: `new Date%9&&a` is shorter by three characters (`Date` can be called as a no-parens constructor and `Date` objects are generally math'ed as numeric timestamps) and meets the community consensus that [single-use modulo-time is generally acceptable as a random number source](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/is-the-current-time-or-date-with-modulo-random-enough)

Comment: @JimboJonny What spec are you looking at?  At https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-math.random it says "approximately uniform distribution over that range."  Omitting a single floating point value at the edge is most definitely "approximately uniform distribution."  I don't see any comments about "all values along that range."

In fact the implementation of Math.random in V8 prior to them switching ot xorshift128+ omitted _many_ values from the range of possible floats, but it still had approximately uniform distribution across the whole range.

Comment: @GrandOpener - It is a fundamental requirement of having a range of "0 to <1" that it includes a possibility of 0, otherwise you have not met the requirement of using the range specified. A range of ">0 to <1" is not the same thing as a range of "0 to <1". Use the wrong range, and you haven't met the requirement. Period.

Comment: @JimboJonny  Your last comment is incorrect.  Is the set of numbers (0.2, 0.3, 0.9) in the range [0, 1)?  Are they greater than or equal to zero and less than one?  Of course they are.  There is no "fundamental requirement" that a set of numbers in a range cover the entire range.  Covering the entire range is a separate requirement from being inside the range, and to my knowledge the spec has never made any coverage requirements.  It requires being inside the range and having "approximately" uniform distribution.  A function that never returns 0 can meet both of those requirements.

Comment: @GrandOpener Regardless of whether it's implemented in such a manner, if the JavaScript spec says it can be in the range of [0, 1), I believe it would be valid to assume 0 is possible.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Agreed.  Code should definitely assume that 0 is possible and be prepared for it.

Comment: @GrandOpener -  If 0.2-0.9 is the maximum range, then you are not expressing a range of 0 to <1. The spec clearly states that you are to express the full range when it tells you that all possible values within the range must be approximately equally represented.

Comment: @GrandOpener - Also, please read more carefully. I never said that any randomly selected set from 0 to <1 would include 0. I said a range of 0 to <1 includes the *possibility* of 0. If you create a function that cannot return zero, then "gives a range of 0 to <1" is not an accurate description of that function, as it overstates its possible range. Even without the next statement in the spec about all values in that range being roughly uniformly distributed your argument would still be poor. With it, it's completely untenable.

Answer (score 7):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 3 bytes

```
x,;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v0LH@v9/AA)

My first submission in ><>, very simple

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 6 byte function

```
z^:?@2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/q@Ks7B2M/mtycRWlFpZmFqUqqOeV5qYWZSarcxUl5qXk52ZWpQJN4EpNzshXSFMAMklm/QcA)

If `y` is the argument, `z^:v` conditionally returns the result `z y` if `v y` returns `1`.  Otherwise it returns `y` unchanged.

`? 2` will return 0 half the time and 1 half the time.

No matter what argument we pass to this function, it will be converted into the constant `2` and then passed to `z^:?`.

So half time the result will be `2`, and half the time it will error when trying to execute the non-existent verb `z`.

### alternative full programs

Though these may look like snippets they should count as full programs in the context of this challenge.

4 bytes thanks to Bubbler:

```
q:?2
```

5 bytes thanks to Adam:

```
0^.?2
```

Comment: Wouldn't `0^.?2` work?

Comment: My first instinct was that that was a snippet, but on 2nd thought it probably counts as a valid program.

Comment: `q:?2` also works (`q:0` is a domain error).

Answer (score 6):

## Python <= 3.7, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

`lambda x:id(x.__dir__)`

Included for its weirdness rather than its brevity. This will cause a [segmentation fault](https://bugs.python.org/issue33930) in obscure cases involving deep recursion. A fix is being applied, but only to python versions >=3.8.

The crash only occurs on cleanup when *exiting* the interpreter, but an example of how to call this function (and reproduce the segfault) can be found here: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRocIqM0WjQi8@PiWzKD5e83@Fgq1CflJWanKJhiZXWn6RQoVCZp5CUWJeeqqGYbyBgQEIa1pxKQABSC1cK1gkTaNC8z8A)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! The question doesn't involve taking any input, so I'm not sure how to call your function? Could you include a [Try it online!](https://tio.run/#python3) link to demonstrate?

Comment: Thank you, have edited my answer — please let me know if there are any other community guidelines I'm missing!

Answer (score 5):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost) -A, 9 bytes (Probability 1/2)

```
\\\\
%1-@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/PwYIuFQNdR3@//@v6wgA) [Verification<sup>1</sup>](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/PwYIuFQNdR3@//@vGwYA)

As an introduction to Lost for anyone unfamiliar, Lost is a 2-D programming language in which the start location and direction are selected at random at the beginning of the program.  This source of randomness is what we use in this challenge.

We want some start locations that will cause an error and some that will not.

The program will error if it starts on the character `%` going right (or down).  In this case it will encounter the ops `%1-@` before termination.  This pushes `-1` and exits.  Since `-1` is not a valid character code this causes an error in character mode.

The program will terminate safely if it starts on the character `%` going left (or up).  In this case it will encounter the ops `%@` before termination.  This does nothing and exits.

Since we have a path that errors and one that does not, all that remains is to know that every path terminates, which is guarenteed by the `\\\\`.  So this program is valid.

We could shorten this significantly if there was not a termination requirement.  The program :

```
%1-@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/X9VQ1@H///@6jgA)

Either errors, terminates cleanly or loops forever, and it selects which at random with the following probabilities:

- **1/2** Non-terminating
- **1/4** Errors
- **1/4** Terminates cleanly

---

<sup>1: For verification we turn off character mode.  All outputs containing negative numbers are the ones that will error in character mode.</sup>

Comment: Could this be golfed by erroring through running out of memory?

Comment: @emanresuA I mean `%1@` should eventually run out of memory.  (Probably, I ran it for like 10 minutes and it didn't crash, it should be allocating new memory but it would take a very long time to crash anyway)  However I don't think this [is allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24412/56656).

Comment: My interpretation of that rule is that you can't simultaneously assume unlimited memory and assume finite memory (or similar) however since this program doesn't have to handle any input it's perfectly fine to have it push 1s until it runs out.

Answer (score 5):

## INTERCAL, 10 bytes

```
DO%9GIVEUP
```

The only way to terminate an INTERCAL program without an error is to execute a `GIVE UP` statement -- running off the end of the source code is a runtime error.  This program uses INTERCAL's probabilistic execution feature to have a 9% chance of successfully exiting; the rest of the time, it errors out:

```
ICL129I PROGRAM HAS GOTTEN LOST
        ON THE WAY TO WHO KNOWS WHERE
        CORRECT SOURCE AND RESUBNIT
```

Comment: Is this a serious programming language? How old is it?

Comment: @S.S.Anne, [INTERCAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL) was one of the first, if not *the* first, esoteric programming languages, having been created in 1972 as a parody of various programming languages in use at the time.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>17</s></sup> 16 bytes

Random across function calls.

Saved a byte thanks to [newbie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89856/newbie)!!!

```c
f(i){i/=rand();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOlPftigxL0VD07r2f25iZp6GZjVXGpDHVVCUmVeSpqGUnx2TpwTk1/4HAA)

Has a \$\frac1{\text{RAND_MAX} + 1}\$ chance of failing with `Floating point exception`.

**Random across runs.**

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 19 bytes

```c
f(i){i/=(int)&i%3;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOlPfViMzr0RTLVPV2Lr2f25iZp6GZjVXmoahpjVXQRFQKk1DKT87Jk8JyK/9DwA)

Comment: `i;f()` => `f(i)`

Comment: @newbie Nice one - thanks! :-)

Comment: Why is it necessary do `i/=` rather than `i/`? Does the compiler optimize away the expression as useless otherwise?

Comment: @xnor Yup, the compiler simply chucks the code away as dead-code.

Comment: *"so a random number with the same seed is not valid"*

Comment: @S.S.Anne: I think we can justify this because it's a *function* not a program.  If called multiple times, it will generate new random numbers and update the seed, not reusing the same seed for every call.  p.s. I posted an x86 machine code answer to this which you might find interesting.  My first idea was div by rdrand, but came up with some less boring stuff.

Comment: @S.S.Anne No more `rand()`.

Comment: `rand()` was better in some ways.  On normal implementations, if this was called in a loop the address of `i` will be the same every time.  But yes, across different invocations of the same program, stack ASLR randomizes the high bits so mod 3 will work.  (On my x86-64 Arch Linux desktop, `printf("%s\n", &i);` shows the address of a local across runs is randomized as much as possible, only the low 4 bit being constant (because the ABI requires 16-byte stack alignmnent).  Unlike file-mapped and BSS segments where ALSR has page granularity.  (Although %3 would still work, I was just curious)

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting! :-)

Comment: You have to use `rand()`, following the definition for randomly: *"Use your language's built-in random number generator,
Use `/dev/random`, or
Create a RNG that is equivalent to a standard RNG (such as the Mersenne Twister)."*

Comment: @Noodle9: You might want to include both answers: one for random across program invocations (address mod 3), one for random across calls (`rand()`).  Neither are universal.  Using `time()` instead of `rand()` could sort of work, but unless you pass `time(0)` to avoid just returning `-1` from EFAULT it's not really valid.  And it only faults if run with the system clock set to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).

Comment: @PeterCordes Good idea - thanks! :-)

Comment: 18 bytes `f(i){i/=(i=&i)%3;}`

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 5 bytes

```
v
x+;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v4yrQtv6/38A)

### Explanation

The pointer will be represented by a hashtag symbol. It will replace in bewteen these spaces:

```
v 
x + ;
```

Ok, explanation start.

The instruction pointer goes down.

```
v*
x + ;
```

The step is randomized.

```
v
x*+ ;
```

Case 1: Error

```
v
x +*;
```

It tries to pop two items, but there is nothing on the stack. Cue error.

Case 2: Exit gracefully

```
v
x + ;*
```

It loops to the right side, and ends on the semicolon.

Comment: Why not just `x+;` for 3 bytes?

Comment: I think it only goes perpendicular.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by that, but it appears another ><> answer in this thread has done that 3 byter (well, something tantamount to it).

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

```apl
÷?2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862tP@H95ub/QfyOICigNF0/4DAA)

(Requires `IO←0`)

Inverse of random boolean (any range including 0 would work). I expect this'll be a common technique...

```apl
÷    ⍝ Inverse
 ?2  ⍝ Random number in [0,1]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 10 bytes

```powershell
1/(random)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BfoygxLyU/V/P/fwA)

`get-random` returns an int between 0 and 0x7FFFFFFF so it'll eventually divide by 0. Maybe...

Answer (score 4):

## [Google Sheets](https://sheets.google.com), 8 bytes

```
=0/RAND(
```

Google will a closing parentheses automatically to give `=0/RAND()`.

Since `RAND()` produces a uniformly random between 0 inclusive and 1 exclusive and to 15 decimal points of accuracy, is has a 0.0000000000001% chance of returning exactly 0 and causing the `#DIV/0!` error.

Answer (score 4):

## [Metatape](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Metatape), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

```
x?(
```

*-1 byte thanks to [Hactar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59288/hactar), the language creator, on Discord*

Initially, the tape head is within a tape and pointing to a null cell. The command `x` exits the current cell, creating a new tape and putting the initial tape within it. Now the tape head is within a tape and pointing at a tape.

The `?` command then generates a random bit, setting the current cell of the tape to null if it is `0` and doing nothing if it is `1`. Then the `(` command jumps to the next `|` or `)` characters in the code if and only if the current cell is null, and does nothing otherwise. Thus, if the bit generated by `?` is `0`, the interpreter will throw an error, as there is no `|` or `)` to jump to. On the other hand, Metatape does not implicitly check for every `(` matching with a `)`, so if the bit generated by `?` is `1`, no error will be thrown.

EDIT: After further clarification with the language's creator, I found that the last sentence I wrote may not apply to all interpreters, and thus this answer might not work for all interpreters. Oops.

Answer (score 4):

## Z80 machine code, <strike>6</strike> 5 bytes

I finally managed to reduce it to 5 bytes and also make it more well-behaved at the same time:

```
ED 5F B7 C0 76
```

Explanation:

```
ED 5F   LD A, R  ; get non-deterministic value (00-7F) from memory refresh register
B7      OR A, A  ; set Z flag if A is zero
C0      RET NZ   ; return normally, unless we were unlucky and got zero
76      HALT     ; halt the CPU
```

Alternatively to the `HALT` instruction `RST` could be used to call an error handler.

Other approaches that use 6 bytes and fail in a less well-behaved way:

---

```
ED 5F 17 32 06 00
```

Explanation:

```
ED 5F      LD A, R       ; get random value (00-7F) from refresh count register
17         RLA           ; rotate left one
32 06 00   LD (0006), A  ; write the byte immediately following this instruction.
```

There is a chance that this results in one of the conditional RET instructions to be written after the code, which returns normally if the condition happens to be met, which is the case for `RET NZ (C0)`, `RET NC (D0)`, `RET PE (E8)` and `RET M (F8)`. Otherwise, a random instruction is executed and the program counter runs into whatever is in RAM after that, failing horribly. If bit 8 of the R register was somehow set (which doesn't normally happen), or any instruction with an opcode up to 7F would somehow end the program normally, this could be reduced to 5 bytes. The address operand in the last instruction must be set relative to where the code is actually located.

---

```
ED 5F B7 28 FE C9
```

Explanation:

```
ED 5F   LD A, R  ; get non-deterministic value (00-7F) from memory refresh register
B7      OR A, A  ; set Z flag if A is zero
28 FE   JR Z, -2 ; infinite loop if Z-flag is set
C9      RET      ; return
```

An infinite loop might not really count as an 'error' though. An alternative solution (same length), inspired by Peter Cordes' x86 solution, is to mess with the return address:

---

```
E5 ED 5F AC 67 E9
```

Explanation:

```
E5      POP HL   ; get return address from stack
ED 5F   LD A, R  ; get non-deterministic value (00-7F) from memory refresh register
AC      XOR A, H ; this will only leave H intact 
67      LD H, A  ;       if R was zero by chance
E9      JP HL    ; jump to (probably broken) return address
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Could you include a copy of the code without comments or extraneous elements?

Comment: sure, like this?

Comment: Yeah that's good.  Normally a user won't get a message unless you put an @ before their name in your comment btw.

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter good to know! Thanks for helping me along :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org), <sup><s>8</s></sup> 7 bytes, \$ \approx \frac{1}{10}\$ chance of success

```
>$$
<*4
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhbL7VRUuGy0TCA8qCBMEgA)

Determines whether the process ID ends in `4`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

I haven't used Jelly for a long time, it's time for me to pick it up again.

```
2X’İX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98o4lHDzCMbIv7/BwA)

## Explanation

```
2X    Pick random from [    1,  2]
  ’   Decrement:       [    0,  1]
   İ  Reciprocal:      [  inf,  1]
    X randrange 1      [Error,  1]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, 13 bytes

```matlab
det(0:rand*2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/JbVEw8CqKDEvRctI8/9/AA)

#### How it works

`rand` produces a random number with uniform distribution between `0` and `1`. So the range `0:rand*2` may be `0` (1×1 matrix) or `[0 1]` (1×2 matrix). `det` tries to compute the determinant, which is only defined for square matrices.

Comment: Try `nan(rand)` or `inf(rand)` in MATLAB for nine bytes which works only for rand values zero and one. In Octave, we can do better with `0(rand)` for seven bytes.

Comment: @AravindhKrishnamoorthy Thanks for the suggestion, but `rand` draws numbers from the _open_ interval (0,1) (both in Matlab and in Octave), so it wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: Oh indeed! Then we've to use randn and waste a byte :(

Comment: @AravindhKrishnamoorthy That works, but it relies on the fact that the ideally continuous random variable is actually discrete, and thus it has some non-zero probability of producing an integer. I say "but" because it's a "dirty" trick, but then golfing is all about that kind of tricks. Anyway, it's a totally different approach, you should post that yourself (and will get my upvote)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
Î)ΩE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cJ/muZWu//8DAA)

```
Î        Push 0 and input, ie. [0, ""] b/c input blank
 )       Wrap total stack to an array
  Ω      Push random element of a, ie. [0, ""]
   E     For-loop in [1 .. a]
```

where `a` is the top of the stack

Errors when `""` is randomly selected & for loop is attempted on it.
Proceeds when `0` is randomly selected & for loop is attempted on it.

Comment: Is there any single character function that errors with 0 and works with 1? Because then you could replace Î) with T

Comment: I didn't find one @CommandMaster

Comment: 3 bytes: `®ΩE`. ® pushes -1 by default, and then the Ω choses either - or 1

Answer (score 3):

## SQL (Oracle), <strike>37</strike>33 Bytes

```sql
SELECT 1/INSTR(UID,3) FROM DUAL;
```

Fails if the User Session doesn't have a 3 in it.
Edit: Was using SYSDATE, but UID is shorter.  Although I'm kinda sad.  I liked having a function that worked in March, but not February.

Comment: Although this answer is interesting, the requirements state it must be random. I'm not very good with SQL, but wouldn't `SELECT 1/RAND()` work (errors if `RAND()` is 0, which has a very, very small chance of happening)?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms RAND isn't a valid function in Oracle.

Comment: I have not used oracle for ages. But would the work instead ? x int:=1/INSTR(UID,3)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```r
if(rexp(1)>1)a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzNNoyi1okDDUNPOUDPx/38A)

R doesn't throw errors often. In particular, dividing by 0 doesn't lead to an error (`1/0=Inf`); nor does attempting to access an out-of-bounds entry in a vector (outputs `NA` with a warning). Two easy ways to get an error are: 1. an `if` statement gives an error if it is not fed a `TRUE`/`FALSE` value; 2. trying to access a non-existing object.

Here, if the random variate is >1, we try to access `a` which doesn't exist, so R throws `Error: object 'a' not found`. If the random variate is <1, nothing happens.

---

Previous version:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 15 bytes

```r
if(T[rexp(1)])1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzNNIyS6KLWiQMNQM1bT8P9/AA)

Here, `rexp(1)` generates a realization of the exponential distribution, i.e. a random value \$x\in\mathbb R_+\$.

- if \$x<1\$ then `T[x]` is an empty logical vector and R throws an `Error: argument is of length zero`
- if \$1\leq x<2\$ then `T[x]` is `TRUE` and R outputs `1` without error
- if \$2\leq x\$ then `T[x]` is `NA` and R throws an `Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

An error is thrown with probability \$1-e^{-1}+e^{-2}\approx 0.767\$.

Answer (score 3):

### [Compiled Stax](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joshudson/stax/master/staxc/staxc1.stax), <strike>28 27</strike> 25 bytes

Requires 116 TB RAM, and ulimit -s set to 116TB.

```
8000000000000{1-cy{}?}Y!
```

At present time, obvious ways to golf this fail to compile due to the compiler not supporting the requisite language feature.

This program attempts a recursive block invocation with a depth of 8000000000000, which in turn tries to create 8000000000000 16 byte stack frames on the runtime stack. This either succeeds or fails with probability of about .5 depending on how far apart the program and the top of the stack are in address space are.

I am using the environment's RNG that is actually documented to be random to make this fault or not fault.

And recursive said there's no such thing as nondetermistic stax.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms: But it is random. The top-of-the-stack address is documented to be randomized.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm just used to people not reading the spec and posting answers that abuse undefined behavior. Nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 209 bytes

```
Go to Heisenberg's:w 1 r 3 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.Go to Magic Eight:s 1 r 1 l 3 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Taxi Garage:e 2 l 2 r.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0msyPz/3z1foSRfwSM1szg1Lym1KF292KpcwVChSMEYiA0VcvQCMpOzSwsUEhUKEouBatJTixTS8zPz0kHafBPTM5MVXDPTM0qIVgexEEnEqhhsH9AukJ14zXGuTM7Jz0uFmhEC9ICCe2JRYnqqVaqCEVC/EVD///8A)

Ungolfed and commented:

```
[ Heisenberg's produces random integers ]
Go to Heisenberg's:w 1 r 3 r 1 l.
[ Pickup two random integers ]
Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.
Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.
[ Magic Eight compares two numeric passengers ]
[ It returns the first passenger if it is less than the second and no one if it is not ]
Go to Magic Eight:s 1 r 1 l 3 r.
[ Try to pickup a passenger, which will error if there isn't anyone waiting ]
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
[ Return to the garage to avoid getting the "you're fired" error ]
Go to Taxi Garage:e 2 l 2 r.
```

[Try the ungolfed and commented version online!](https://tio.run/##jVI9T8MwEN37K566dEGVWrauCBUGJIS6RQzGuTonEjs6O4T8@nC2SikCIQYP53t@X3Iy7zzPFe6II/kXEreK6CXUg6UIMb4OHdgnciQRz4t9QArf0LsRGwiu9WzQrhcVHtm@Dj3SGH4hOC0NehOVQ2/hAnuXaR@MY4tbdk1a/x9YXY6woeuNqPcs74eORFdniuygwn2CUBrEK6ohHFliupDhIziBI1qKGWF8gUWywdfQRPABwdMX0Id07ubCzC6WarSWXE92epApY/of2a4wNmwbjNy2IJFQbKisqEz0q6S6U9YcDafcwt9N3ky2VXSWfCpJ82UO4YwYR3kyb4FrOEqFLu@WUxhWUvqgenly8RnroB8F@/J6R9hqpK1GmucP)

Answer (score 3):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 3 bytes

```c
/1R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltV9vKEf5s/4rFOdhaWw6SoOfc2sgckgs5nBLIhaT3A7iJkNegU1l2JRlCCf3r6czsi1a2SZv28sGydp@ZnXl2dmbWxP3bOP7@KsnidDkR@0U5Seav70ZNeyRNbmpDcfm4ECugPMlua0NlMpOYiZgmmWBpytJ5dksfzebODltm8Xw2E1nJyrukYCmCpvOcRewmmrBCiAlMRCVCc1Eu86xgHptnLI@yicNxWKvGpZyvnAV7e3/2/WbTrPnx7NN75levlx8vWFC9/vXwgu1Vr8dnb9kv1evFJ@ZX4OPTSwt79unUgn46e394@Ren4MzBjzb7l/8nbmYPL2FZORnfRTnr8krARoGtRsVoxPaqubOj33Eyg0ny6BvD7/v7KxhchjDoJmDSlCOwhnlzfn5KIPw4ICcH6JtlyMU7CQB5y9b7KF0Kzq@yMW82yQ/Y86txeNE6Oj92vu/4F985fGsN5WQXZkU0YyHChs0m6FpEeSEczp6ajQQ2PRk2GzBKel3WnUI4wAgJx/BezhZusciugnH45LneM@hoJKCO8PD0cABiACNvwR7uklIUiygWzQZ8T4UD4yDuSDNc1rour7Pr6XXOnp6vxg4fvGpxMqWRTJljrA1Z51WHM6lCj27B6HUGw72eHAE7GyIthD3wLM2J70T8dwrjbDm7EXmh7GFOUkyS26TUWmF1dMd3jUfy2WW@x3qsqyzv9Tjrs47XgSXQ0oSrw8B0JEgxCobhqg33UZ5EN6nQVoAR6fxB5E4M62lD2LdvTBsX01tMRHzucEVPssH1JPRd2KPQDK9Yh2dLxSBAssly4eCWMsVpn8HbusEyjxRSmzTjutOpbGp15KaBMHhgjGKgBPIOfAfLFlGBKUWAsigvAaw2oKsZxQ2NOXqijbUOzIvGwqfPaaMbFRlkPoZumcwzMBsj1huDabFmpFguFkg411GlR2z67fgD2i2yUYcO5UUGcQxZCiNXWS5Z@dgxR1kOHOMAZqwBZio0UwcZJTnpqoN2o6lRms5jZ89zfY4O4rBxghzMlmka5Y@2o9X@XFjb86FjLKMFlfwyW5GmJXxcQiWFTZ4eHr15@@W3rdNfzy2HbbU3yUa9wbrerZridyeXL2gsRU4qocKwfywj/Ypq7@0ldteXkAS86xguTjZwQcJ7deE65plSZb7McIeGKtN2y3nh6FxJBwBCu0xiRrM3y@lVsDdWdsiNblN6MAYUCzhW5dQBKPi/naaTls47VGlcVLKqAA6FUSBrmFy/httn/m7dT3QeY/GAtcp8KVoQg2YcQxLGpxFkEJxoYWS1KhLQT/RdFRui4/Ob@TyFmZs6Ay/6Wrn1I4e6P@@RbebNmpkp2pj9oTZC0JbzNHVsU13muVAh/geTszWTsQq/P/xw5mItloEGrydXvud5EE7gCrzqtyL5p/hcMnwMrRi1vEUG4M3Fj4A@d0Nfl3TMcFjV8UGfgXzsAuD45PSoy6aQHIcNE9pqPUzDcbRwU5FRB2BxpXshyRmcu5fIWBXE2oSlDQuOk1AvAbV4n7gYQlFJcNLkjXi2WNkBIikZVykEaUrGuEzxkJTxndMFZtZaJ@CIqb8Y61TnsDNguIoEhEgoNl@QhXmbnFLqVftXC1k@pCpcIajHLHMsXdRmXo35UxVm0EBRbpcLX8DCdd2yp257X6fwVwE/ABCUSopuRYk9utOmrWzjBmGFnCQZHyZTx6HtxH4gvsvRFBfClHO5y6E33GgqPDh1AXK9I7mebBwxGSg@htpc5EilzsrKN5U7Em9m3lYzKGkzbDBfAIPBAOEXLuYLkTnWwm4rb1GnAFaFM1koIRzDwNv7hcZVb@HIhmQKpk/QKejgIGJdbO8ADq0DveEasLSOLgcGWS@kTggPLCC5ohv00FpENWrohiywW5aKxsqT38AT8RW6ODzsa35u1Tad7gFbmMjWgKdr0QGrpHVeLPivnYFqEzfEsUl8qgC1zqgrdrAEcV2DRqM9XvWVa9lQi15Sb@hsFyhYPwvrwkAndD72upBIeauC6gmsLiLKlNqXKpgqWfYOqNSiWDivWMCDIe89SJrczxp1rN2my1O/j9Cx7HKvqdtuaLO2X3cLsMeBN870Ucst85dloXffxIRs9aRBPWMQpUlIl5iRMbSs7ZHNdKO@2/Imimho@5mOpUDuOba/dBjkBhAKh/GUh9rLgG8O1Tgq9UM1nX6voonr76iLQzPq0rNUOUL51V@LTivasVOv2yuFutXubGBhtTpv4KG7xoPc100szDa41iVMaCshAShBDmXIsHMNdzwEDft90qeIooq5utGS0bJ2@nd@SMzOZmK2fyi0vVnob8RmzSF5c6CxwPZyqGiXrIes7xuWCQvU@3DO@j6cMd8GBz@J3of0WMOGIUJp3YEe8TTlRHQw8hTXAadupRsS/83VA0GT5ApcESjBYomB73hjuBO56BQsm0MLnaRlkrGH6BF4Y5M5XElLcStykFnMM5GVSYSXCDjJc/Yg2F10LwCoFCG8ZLMoW0L4PL7GUfTuBhkHKoiJYpmW@JsBLW4Snob0bYxecoUyW85AVtSjvpeR3suGGNh@DeXR9TxKsTY@gtfZJBUT9qUy@4vR8oTfZF9mLVI5M0Jl/b5@px8BcbcI2rVMfzZ5cJ@CdaXwYdKr5cWwnhUPmH349@1jgKID9Rtbm0nAAav1iTToMisbog5PSuqSG8g6gNitEKqN1QWN4FBiaM0n8wGbiVm8wDDL2OjLwf/ryugPcGWkXdna4EuofFGuHLzMvlx1g8k4fcBqgMAgAl1AtzbZWb0Y93TmsRUY89pV@kNfNtWGA1tSpRIj/@2/kVc5yFJj5IedgY2utbmr2LDKuvXpn77H6N62usggrlG7zJhUSBjUOA5r0laaRAlE9HpGTJr8O7gnf/SyG82ad8zuXZTYSb1rR6glfxAMdi1a3skrQ2h1WD27AK1fkTJ18XDNWditNbSXkugVpcPVkhdsKnm73PQBgZHeo8H/0BChYfjErYhN82/aIbs3CsBDXLXnY5NEDYKMfzlJD0L01EmA1SdiGkGSBM90h5lkMJlM6DekKC6hTHW24w72nDjC2QuXWFRmaiB0g@p3hFmUZNissii/jV1S2u3C93uOv1bR9ZL@S@ORNfVr3PP3fwM)

Has a roughly \$\frac{1}{65536}\$ chance of dividing by zero.

The classic `1/rand()` trick. Assumes that dividing by zero throws an error, of course.

Uncommenting the line at the top of the header code will `srand` with a seed that will cause glibc's `rand()` to return `0xe7d0000`, which when masked by `0xFFFF`, results in `0`.

Answer (score 3):

****><>, 4 bytes****

The **!** skips the next instruction, even if it would give an error.
The **x** set the pointer's direction to a random direction. It can make it go up or down but if the pointer reaches the edge then it wraps around.
The **;** ends the program.
The **{** can be replaced with any character as long as it's not a valid command in ><>.

```
!{x;
```

https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X7G6wvr/fwA
Try it online!

Comment: Welcome to the site! [`x;{`](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v8K6@v9/AA "><> – Try It Online") does the same thing using the wrapping.

Comment: what language is this? brainf?

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 24 bytes

```c
main(i){i/=(time(0)%3);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///PzcxM08jU7M6U99WoyQzN1XDQFPVWNO69v9/AA)

## C, 20 bytes

```c
main(i){i/=time(0);};
```

Will crash once every +/- 68 years.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Answer (score 3):

## [Aussie++](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus/), 78 bytes

```
G'DAY MATE!
IMPOHT ME FUNC ChuckSomeDice;
ChuckSomeDice(0,ChuckSomeDice(0,2));
```

Tested in commit 9522366.

`ChuckSomeDice` is the only way to get a random number, but it behaves a bit interestingly:

- If either argument is a finite non-integer, it's truncated to an integer.
- Inputs are capped to be no greater than 9223372036854775296.
- NaN is treated as 0.
- If both arguments (let's call them `x` and `y`) are integers, and `y` is greater than `x`, it gets a random integer in `[x, y)`.
- If `x` is less than `y`, it prints `OI MATE, CAN YA FUCKIN' COUNT?? START MUST BE LESS THAN END!!` to STDERR, but continues execution.
- If `x` is equal to `y`, it panics. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus/issues/41).

The result is stored as a double, so calling e.g. `ChuckSomeDice(9223372036854775295, 1/0)` only ever produces either 9223372036854775000 or 9223372036854776000.

**TL;DR:** The arguments can't be equal, and behind the scenes it's likely casting between `i64` and `f64`.

So, I get either 0 or 1 randomly, and then get a random number between 0 and the result. If that was also 0, it panics. If that was 1, it returns 0.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 17 bytes

```
1/RandomInteger[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n27731A/KDEvJT/XM68kNT21KDr2f0BRZl6JgkP6//8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

-1 thanks to FryAmTheEggman.

```
lO2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8ff6P9/AA)

Comment: Using `l` is shorter than `/1`, though there still might be something better.

Answer (score 2):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 22 bytes

Just like the other answers...

```erlang
f()->1/rand:uniform().
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5z/U/TUNT185QvygxL8WqNC8zLb8oV0NT739uYmaeRjxQKg3EAwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 3 bytes

```
~~/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//@/rk7//38A)

This works by pushing two random numbers onto the stack ane dividing them. If the second number is 0, then it errors out.

There is indeed a chance for the second number to be 0, but it is highly unlikely that it will be, as the random range used is quite large. But highly unlikely != zero.

If I were to estimate the odds of erroring out, I'd say it'd be something like 1 in `((int​(​"​9​"​*​3234​) ** 2) + 21) * 2`.

Comment: Hey, look, it worked: `TypeError: integer argument expected, got float`

Comment: With a higher chance of erroring... `~:/`

Comment: @petStorm that's still the same chance.

Comment: Is "highly unlikely != non-zero" intended to be "highly unlikely != zero"?

Answer (score 2):

**[Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 9 bytes**

```
1/rand(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31C/KDEvRcNI8/9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 28 bytes

```c
f(i){srand(&i);i/=rand()&1;}
```

Crashes approximately every other time it's run. Abuses ASLR.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzurgoMS9FQy1T0zpT3xbM1lQztK79n5lXopCbmJmnUZafmaLJVc2lAARpGprWXLX/AQ)

Comment: Since we ultimately rely on `&i` for randomness, why not get rid of the `rand` stuff? `f(i){i/=(int)&i<0;}` works.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Because then it would violate the rules for "randomly".

Comment: I just reread the specification - apparently this challenge is much different than I thought...

Comment: @SurculoseSputum: I think that's a constant, but such an expression should exist.

Comment: -1 byte: `f(i){i/=rand(srand(&i))&1;}`

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 1/32767 chance of success, 12 bytes

```
exit $RANDOM
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell) Windows, 10 bytes

```powershell
ps(random)
```

`get-random` returns an int between 0 and 0x7FFFFFFF so it'll eventually match some PID and `ps` will [get the process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Process) that are running on the local computer. Maybe...

---

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell) Linux, 11 bytes

```powershell
gps(random)
```

`TIO`  does not work because `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`. Please use your own `Powershell`. :)

Answer (score 2):

## Batch, 11 bytes

```
%random:1=%
```

Has a probability of <s>1/65536</s> Corrected by @Neil, 5/32768 (~0.0015%) to not generate an error.

Edit: Alternatively,

```
%random:~1%
```

Comment: 5/32768, I think? (`1`, `11`, `111`, `1111` and `11111` won't error, and `%random%` only goes from `0` to `32767`.)

Comment: @Neil you're right, will fix that

Answer (score 2):

## Red - 24 bytes

```
x: now/time 1 / x/minute
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, I've tried to correct the code formatting in your answer.  You can revise it if I have something wrong.  Let me know if you are having trouble with the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
®ΩF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0LpzK93@/wcA) Has a \$\frac12\$ chance of erroring.

```
®ΩF  # full program
  F  # for N in (0, ...
 Ω   # random element from...
®    # register_c (starts at -1)...
     # (implicit) split into separate characters...
  F  # ... - 1)...
     # (implicit) do nothing
     # (implicit) end loop
```

`-1` split into separate characters is `["-", "1"]`, so it picks a random element from there. Either it picks `1` and does nothing once, or it picks `-`, tries to loop `-` times, and crashes. Unlike `ï`, the built-in integer conversion function, it doesn't handle errors (if it can't be converted to an integer). So, it throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 4 bytes

50/50 chance of a divide by zero error. `X` causes the head to go in a random cardinal direction, `/` is obviously division, and `@` ends the program. Because of edge bouncing, the head traveling up or left is the same as it traveling down or right since it's in a corner.

```
X/
@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/z9Cn8vh/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 10 bytes

```
1.div rand
```

Can't do `1/rand`, since 1/0.0 in Ruby is Infinity, not an error.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31AvJbNMoSgxL@X/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
∆Ṙl
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%88%86%E1%B9%98l&inputs=&header=&footer=)

I  think this has a \$\frac{1}{2^{19937}}\$ chance of not erroring, but I'm not sure - Vyxal is written in Python, so it's whatever chance python's PRNG has of returning 0.

Answer (score 2):

## [Minim](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Minim), 6 Bytes

```
[R*S].
```

Accesses memory at index **R**andomNumber *times* Memory**S**ize.

**R** is between **0** and **1** *inclusive*, and **S** is the memory scope size in elements. If **R = 1**, then the index will be out of bounds, and throws an error.

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/KakkoiiChris/Minim)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>17</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```javascript
new Date%2?a:0
```

Errors if current millisecond is odd

`new Date` returns current epoch time
`%2` modulo 2, returns 1 if odd, 0 if even
if it's a truthy value (1), `a` will throw as it's an undefined variable

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/L7VcwSWxJFXVyD7RyuD/fwA)

Comment: `new Date` should work instead of `Date.now()`, saving 2 bytes. You could also replace the `throw 1` with something like `a` (which causes a ReferenceError).

Comment: i never knew new doesn't require `()`, i completely forgot about reference error lol

Comment: You can save a byte with `new Date%2?a:0`

Comment: ah yes, ternary, the thing i overuse the most in js

Comment: @Ectogen Or another with `new Date%2&&a`, but then it's identical to mine

Comment: haha yeah, i saw that, `&&` only does the next thing if the first thing is truthy

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Feck it, [may as well post this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203261/make-your-code-error-but-only-sometimes#comment532978_233458). Similar in concept to but derived independently from Etheryte's solution. Predicated on the fact that JavaScript's `toString` method can only handle bases 2-36 so it, therefotre, has a 20% chance of throwing a `RangeError` (`toString() radix argument must be between 2 and 36`) - change the `A` to alter the odds of an error occurring.

```
sAö
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=c0H2) (errors are displayed below the output field)

```
sAö     :Implicit input of integer U, defaulting to 0
s       :Convert to string in base
 A      :  10
  ö     :  Random integer from range [0,A)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle), 5 bytes

Contains invalid UTF-8, so I can't post it here. Instead, have a hexdump reversible with `xxd -r`:

```
00000000: 2437 40f7 2e                             $7@..
```

When reading the file, the interpreter starts by loading it as UTF-8 and converting it to a list of 24-bit integers (effectively UTF-32 on many machines due to struct padding). If it encounters an invalid UTF-8 sequence, it doesn't immediately error; rather, it takes that character as U+FFFD and keeps going. Once it's done, it makes the program length be a triangular number by appending `.` (U+002E) as necessary.

Currently, the interpreter stops with an error when it attempts to execute a character that isn't a valid opcode, but this behavior isn't specified. Any invalid opcode I choose could be added in the future, invalidating my answer.

Any character, that is, except for U+FFFD. When the interpreter attempts to execute `0xfffd`, it writes an error message to STDERR and exits with code 1:

```
Unicode replacement character (U+FFFD) detected in source. Please check encoding.
```

The sequence `f72e` is invalid UTF-8, so when the program is loaded in it looks like this:

```
  $
 7 @
� . .
```

The `$` instruction pushes a random integer to the stack, uniformly distributed in the range [-8 388 608, 8 388 607]. Then, `7` is a branch instruction based on the sign of the value on top of the stack. If the value is positive, the IP reaches the `@`, terminating the program gracefully. If the value is negative, the IP reaches the invalid character, triggering the encoding error.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 4 bytes

```
VRCk
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZLwoKcsyFMqAhMBgA)

#### Explanation

`k` is a preinitialized variable containing the string `,` . `RC` chooses one of its characters at random, and `V` attempts to evaluate it as Pip code. If the space was chosen, the evaluation is successful and returns nil. If the comma was chosen, the interpreter crashes:

```
Fatal error during execution: Parsing error while evaluating ",": Hit end of tokens while parsing expression
Program terminated.
```

Comment: A bit boring, but [`/r`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbrlS7IKlpSVpuhaL9IsgDCh_AZQGAA) works if you add -w

Comment: @emanresuA That's a warning, not an error--the difference being that it doesn't cause the program to terminate abnormally, as specified in the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 2 bytes

Sometimes segfaults, sometimes doesn't.

```
<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fRu//fwA)

Comment: Isn't this implementation based, not random?

Comment: sometimes malloc allocates a bigger page so you can read something before the tape, and sometimes malloc allocates smaller page so reading something before the tape segfaults

Comment: personally after mashing the run button for a while, I've seen two segfaults so far

Comment: That's just because you're mashing the run button too fast. Also, this uses neither options 1, 2, nor 3 from the meta consensus.

Comment: `+[<[-]+]` doesn't segfault on TIO, so I don't think this is valid. In fact, if the `[-]` is removed, it halts, so the tape is seemingly looped.

Answer (score 1):

### Windows Batch, <strike>17</strike>15 bytes

```
set/a1/%random%
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `x=`.

Comment: indeed, -2 bytes thanks to @Neil

Answer (score 1):

### [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications), <s>46</s> <s>42</s> <s>35</s> <s>25</s> 13 bytes

Thanks to @Taylor Scott

```vb
?1/Int(9*Rnd)
```

This code only works inside the Immediate Window.

Comment: If you make this an immediate window function, you can get it down to `?1/Int(9*rnd)`

Comment: @Taylor Scott, I didn't know you can do that. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 4 bytes

```
?@
=
```

Executing `=` is of the only ways I can get Befunge to actually error (a `/` won't work there because `0/0` evaulates to `0` in Befunge-98 and asks the user in Befunge-93).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/396By/b/fwA)

The `?` turns the IP in a random direction. If it goes horizontally (1/2 chance), it hits the `@` and terminates successfully. If it goes vertically, it hits the `=` and uses the empty stack (interpreted as the empty string) as the argument. This throws a segfault in FBBI (which implements `=` as a C `system()` call).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
9XRy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98yIghIAgA)

Errors roughly 55% of the time

### How it works

```
9XRy - Main link. Takes no arguments
9X   - Generate a random number from 1 to 9
  R  - Get the range from 1 to that number
   y - Translate, by pairs
```

`y` splits a flat array `[a, b, c, d, ..., y, z]` into pairs, `[[a, b], [c, d], ..., [y, z]]`, then replaces `a` with `b`, `c` with `d` etc in the right argument. However, if there are an odd number of elements in the array, it attempts to pop from an empty list when doing the substitution, which errors.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

Throws if seconds in a new date object are less than 2 or more than 36 since values outside of that range are not valid for base conversion in Japt.

```
sKb
s   // Try to convert the input to a string in base
 K  // new Date()
  b // get seconds.
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=c0ti&input=)

Comment: Nice! I had something similar in `sAö`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 18 bytes

```java
a->1/Math.random()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xD4IwEIV3f8WNbQgIM@JOIpOjcTjbgkVoTVuJieG3Y2lQ@Ia73N3Lu9figHHLH9PzdeskA9ahtVChVPDZgUcqJ0yNTEC5bGa49nIB4i0Y8QqQNA@3MdRQFkPr0Pk2aMmh97bk7IxUzeUKaBpLN54lCCj@048J42O2r9DdE4OK657QKf@ram1Ip1UDEgpIc98OkKUrJ7@Kou2XGZGE4HFGV6dxyT9OXw)

Well yeah, essentially the answer everyone gave but I didn't see Java yet. For the completeness.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 10 bytes

```perl
1/(time%2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/99QX6MkMzdV1Ujz/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 2 bytes

```
ɽ⅟
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//5N5HrfP//7cAAA)

```
ɽ         gets a random 32-bit integer
 ⅟        takes the multiplicative inverse; implicit print
```

Errors on division by 0

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
2rand{/}1if
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/36goMS@lWr/WMDPt/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 16 bytes

```
j=1/mod(i,2)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v/PsjXUz81P0cjUMdLkSs1L@f8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Volatile](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Volatile), 3 bytes

```
~~/
```

`~` pushes a random number onto the stack (which may include zero), and `/` pops two numbers and divides them. If the first `~` pushes a zero, then the program errors.

Answer (score 0):

### (plain) pdfTeX, 34 bytes

```
\ifcase\pdfuniformdeviate9}\fi\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 8 bytes

```perl
1/($$%2)
```

Here `$$` is current PID.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/99QX0NFRdVI8/9/AA)

Comment: The current PID is not considered random for this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## Commodore BASIC (Commodore C64/128, VIC-20, C16/+4, PET, Ultimate64, THEC64 etc)

```
0 on6*rnd(.)goto10,20,30,40,50:goto
10 print"working":goto
20 print"working":goto
30 print"working":goto
40 print"working":goto
```

I've put a prompt in just to show that it does work sometimes too. Essentially, it breaks when the random number generated is rounded to 5 (it generates floating point numbers, but the BASIC interpreter ignores the decimal places).

[image: Commodore C64 BASIC working or not]

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), 30 bytes

```
main(){int*x=0x12345678;*x=1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7M6M69Eq8LWoMLQyNjE1MzcwhrIM7Su/f8fAA)

Will segfault most of the time, but in the case that the program memory gets allocated to that address, it will NOT segfault.

Comment: This isn't considered random for this challenge, similarly to uninitialized memory or your program's PID