# Russian Roulette, varying chances

Tags: code-golf, random, game, error-message

## Russian roulette

It's [Russian roulette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_roulette)! The rules are simple. Shoot a revolver with `n` slots for bullets and one round inside at your head and you *might not die*!
This Question is different from other Russian roulette questions because it takes input to change the chance of exiting with an error.

### Task:

Make a program that takes integer `n` (you can assume that 10<=n<=128) as input and **outputs nothing.**

> but how do I tell if I'm dead?

The program generates a random number x in the range 0 - n inclusive. If x=0 the revolver fires and the program exits with an error (you die). Otherwise the program exits normally.

If your language needs it, the range can be 1-n inclusive.

Standard loopholes forbidden, etc. Upvote answers in *fun* languages! What I'd really like to see is an answer in a language that doesn't have normal randomness (eg. in Befunge where `?` sends you in a random direction instead of giving a random number).

Comment: [sandboxed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/18900#18900)

Comment: If our language natively generates random number in the range of 1 - n inclusive, instead, is that alright?

Comment: I was trying to solve that problem in the sandbox. I'll make it clearer*er* now

Comment: @Wezl Thanks for your edit. Perfect now. You might also want allow a seed for languages without own randomness source.

Comment: Related: [Make your code error, but only sometimes!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203261/make-your-code-error-but-only-sometimes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Russian Roulette](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9062/russian-roulette)

Comment: @pppery But this question takes input and *does not* print " I survived".

Comment: I don't view either of those distinctions as material enough to make it no longer possible to directly copy answers from the other question, make minor tweaks to them, and submit them.

Comment: @pppery the question is simple enough that that could be more work than creating an original response.

Comment: no one's going to beat the 3-byte APL answer but there is still room for "fun" languages.

Comment: Are we allowed to output something or not? It looks like many existing answers output a number for the cases when the program doesn't error

Comment: @mathjunkie You are not supposed to. I will look over the answers.

Comment: @Wezl I would suggest also updating the question to state that more explicitly

Comment: Re-reading the question, I've realised that several of the current answers (mine included) don't meet the spec. My revolver fires when the random number \$x=0\$, not when \$x=n\$. The probability of firing is the same either way, but can you clarify whether firing when \$x=0\$ (or any value other than \$n\$) is acceptable?

Comment: To be clear, I'm specifically referring to cases in which the stated exception for erroring when \$x=0\$—'your language needs it'—doesn't apply.

Comment: @Dingus I initially thought that it was too easy to test if x=0 but most answers are using division by zero so to change it now would be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 5 bytes

```
≔‽‽Ｎθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU8jKDEvJT8XRnnmFZSW@JXmJqUWaWhqauooFGpa//9v9l@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: The `Ｎ` function reads the input number. The `‽` generates a random number between `0` and its argument. However, this errors if the argument is zero. This happens if the inner `‽` randomised a `0`, i.e. 1 in `n` times. The `≔θ` simply serves to make the program do nothing if it was successful.

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

Full program. Exits with code 11 or 0. Requires `⎕IO←0`.

```apl
÷?⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/w9vtwdy/v83NAQA)

`⎕` prompt for `n`

`?` generate random integer in range `0`…`n-1`

`÷` reciprocal (errors if argument is 0)

Comment: Darn! Nice one... I've been waiting for a while to post this, but was waiting for OP to relax the requirements. Otherwise, `÷(⊢-?)⎕` is a little closer to the original, though without ⎕IO←0!

Comment: @AviF.S. Sorry for that. Originally your answer would be eligible but some objected in the sandbox so I changed it... and now I changed it back.

Comment: @Wezl Haha, no worries! Thanks for a challenge simple enough to be accessible to the wildest of esolangs, yet still interesting! Working on an implementation in what you're calling a more 'fun' language!

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 18 bytes

Community consensus is that time can count as a source of randomness. This function will simply take the time in milliseconds modulo the inputted value. If `0`, the function tries to return `a`, which does not exist.

```javascript
n=>Date.now()%n||a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/z9bOJbEkVS8vv1xDUzWvpibxf0FRZl6JRpqGqabmfwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
JlO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3yvH//9/IwMA)

`O` - generate a random integer in the range `0` - `n-1`

`l` - log base 2 of that integer. Throws a `math domain error` if `0` was generated

`J` - assign the value to a variable so that we suppress all output

Comment: ` ` (space) is the more standard way to suppress printing, but this works too.

Answer (score 1):

## Rust + time crate, 38 bytes

```
|n:u8|1/(time::Time::now().second()%n)
```

Defines a closure that takes an unsigned 8-bit integer as input and returns an integer or panics with "attempt to divide by zero".

[try it online](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20f%3D%7Cn%3Au8%7C1%2F(time%3A%3ATime%3A%3Anow().second()%25n)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20test%20if%20it%20crashes%0A%20%20%20%20for%20i%20in%200..1000%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22i%3D%7B%7D%22%2C%20i)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f(20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20std%3A%3Athread%3A%3Asleep(std%3A%3Atime%3A%3ADuration%3A%3Afrom_millis(500))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D).

Our [rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13094/46901) about using the time as randomness state the following (emphasis mine):

> [...] if you have to select one random value per script execution, current **seconds**/milliseconds should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <sup><s>57</s></sup> 43 bytes

Saved 14 bytes synchronously with thanks to [Surculose Sputum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92237/surculose-sputum)!!!

```python
lambda n:1/randint(0,n)
from random import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPylC/KDEvJTOvRMNAJ0@TK60oP1cBJAKkMnML8otKtP6n5RcpZCpk5oHE01M1DA00rdJA5H8A)

Comment: I don't think you need to output anything, so just `lambda n:1/randint(0,n)` should work.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Was just looking into that - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 26 bytes

`id(0)%129%-~n` gives a random number from 0 to n inclusive. It returns an error if it equals 0, because of `ZeroDivisionError`.

```python
lambda n:1/(id(0)%129%-~n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPylBfIzNFw0BT1dDIUlW3Lk/zf0FRZl6JQpqGseZ/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 23 bytes

```python
1/(id(0)%129%-~input())
```

which is a merging of [dingledooper's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204331/75323) with my original one (below). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/31BfIzNFw0BT1dDIUlW3LjOvoLREQ1Pz/38jAA)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
from random import*
1/randint(0,input())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRnqgwQy80o0DHQy8wpKSzQ0Nf//NwIA) Full program.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 14 bytes

```ruby
->n{1./rand~n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cur9pQT78oMS@lLq/2f1q0Wex/AA)

Exits with `ZeroDivisionError` when `rand~n` returns 0. It's helpful that `rand` takes the absolute value of its argument.

Answer (score 0):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) [`j`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends/14339#14339), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

```
g(
```

### Explanation

```
    Implicit input
g   Randrange 1 to input
 (  Decrement the number by 1

Flag:j (Evaluates the J command at the end of the program)

The J command, given a number operand, reciprocals the number.

It throws a 0-division error when the operand is 0.
```

Comment: If `g` uses a range from 1 to input, I don't see how can this crash.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate The range is probably fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 32 bytes

```
@(n)eval('if(randi(n)==n)a;end')
```

`randi(n)` outputs random integer from [1,2,3...n] list

`a` is undefined, so when it is called, program errors out

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 66 bytes

```
0/0 if __import__("random").randint(0,int(input()))==1 else exit()
```

Comment: Welcome to codegolf, and nice first answer! It seems that the double underscore in your code is interpreted as bold mark-up. I suggest you use [this online intepreter](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/30DfQCEzTSE@PjO3IL@oJD5eQ6koMS8lP1dJUw/EyMwr0TDQAZGZeQWlJRqampq2toYKqTnFqQqpFZlAgf//TQA) to format your answer faster - simply click on the "generate perma-link" button (third button at the top), then copy the "Codegolf submission" entry and paste it in your answer here.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
Ý<Ω¬F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8FybcysPrXH7/98QAA)

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 24 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ INT=10

SET @/=floor(rand()*-~@)
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1235151/russian-roulette-varying-chances)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 22 bytes

```java
n->n/=n*=Math.random()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVCxboMwEN35ilMkJAKNk6xNqdShQ4eoA@pUdXCNSZzCYdlHVFTx7fSAkAzxYN@953f37k7yLFen/Kc3la0dwYlz0ZApRbwL7rCiQUWmxoFUpfQe9tIg/AUAtvkujQJPkvg51yaHirkoI2fw8PkF0h38cvwK8Ib0gdK171Y7SbWDIu1x9YzrFON0L@konMS8rqJlvxsFBgl8o5TmlilsbiBX1wO03fC5wThCU15w/WgAzSjl52mScZgksyVgrL3GrBLS2rJ98ew1wuXuSlxsJMkMdaAkqSNEr79K22E9oLlqN9LTnbWedCXqhoTldVARLbLLNDy/foRQbIswDHHxMEySx/Os68np2L4Luv4f)